# How to print instances of a class using print()?

Tags: python, class, printing, object

When I try to `print` an instance of a class, I get an output like this:

```
>>> class Test():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = 'foo'
...
>>> print(Test())
<__main__.Test object at 0x7fc9a9e36d60>
```

How can I make it so that the `print` will show something custom (e.g. something that includes the `a` attribute value)? That is, how can I can define how the instances of the class will appear when printed (their *string representation*)?

---

<sub>See [How can I choose a custom string representation for a class itself (not instances of the class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438) if you want to define the behaviour for the *class itself* (in this case, so that `print(Test)` shows something custom, rather than `<class __main__.Test>` or similar). (In fact, the technique is essentially the same, but trickier to apply.)</sub>

Answer (score 921, accepted):

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "Test()"
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "member of Test"
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> t
Test()
>>> print(t)
member of Test
```

The [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method is what gets called happens when you print it, and the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method is what happens when you use the [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) function (or when you look at it with the interactive prompt).

If no `__str__` method is given, Python will print the result of `__repr__` instead. If you define `__str__` but not `__repr__`, Python will use what you see above as the `__repr__`, but still use `__str__` for printing.

Comment: there's also a __unicode__ method, which you can use instead of __Str__ ; note that it should return a unicode object, not a string (but if you return a string, the conversion to unicode will be done anyway...)

Comment: @kender - I didn't know about it, but in retrospect it makes perfect sense given Python 2.x's broken Unicode handling.

Comment: I think this answer cannot be completed without a link to [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/68269)!

Comment: Saved me! However, after re-implementing the method __repr__(self), print will mislead users. Are you aware of any best practices around this?

Comment: To Java programmers: __str__(self) is like the toString() of the python world

Comment: looks like this is not the case in python3.6 at least to what I'm using

Comment: What if you can't edit the class you want to get information about?.. like something in a shared library / plugin? Surely there must be some kind of generic class method reflection available that doesn't require config?

Answer (score 187):

[As Chris Lutz explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1535336/3357935), this is defined by the `__repr__` method in your class.

From the documentation of [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr):

> For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`, otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets that contains the name of the type of the object together with additional information often including the name and address of the object. A class can control what this function returns for its instances by defining a `__repr__()` method.

Given the following class Test:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Test a:{self.a} b:{self.b}>"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"From str method of Test: a is {self.a}, b is {self.b}"
```

..it will act the following way in the Python shell:

```
>>> t = Test(123, 456)
>>> t
<Test a:123 b:456>
>>> print(repr(t))
<Test a:123 b:456>
>>> print(t)
From str method of Test: a is 123, b is 456
>>> print(str(t))
From str method of Test: a is 123, b is 456
```

If no `__str__` method is defined, `print(t)` (or `print(str(t))`) will use the result of `__repr__` instead

If no `__repr__` method is defined then the default is used, which [is roughly equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777014) to:

```
def __repr__(self):
    cls = self.__class__
    return f"<{cls.__module_}.{cls.__qualname__} object at {id(self)}>"
```

Comment: +1 but your class code's `__str__` is different from the interactive shell's results you give. :P

Comment: Err, oops.. manually modifying REPL output never ends well. I should probably doctest my posts :P

Comment: Thanks. But, the string formatting type (%) in your example is deprecated. Could you change to the str.format() type? :-)

Comment: The `%` string formatting isn't deprecated, from http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html "the % operator is *supplemented* by a more powerful string formatting method, format()"

Comment: Dbr: That is true. Do note that the "What's New In Python 3.0" doc also says "format() method [...] The plan is to eventually make this the only API for string formatting, and to start deprecating the % operator in Python 3.1."

Comment: Pitty, `%`'s been very convenient.

Comment: This won't work if the object is inside another data structure, try: `print([Test(123)])`

Answer (score 114):

If you're in a situation like [@Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917475/10553098) you could try:

```
print(a.__dict__)
```

It goes against what I would consider good style but if you're just trying to debug then it should do what you want.

Comment: Would you know how to know if the dict key has objects in its values?

Comment: @HadoopEvangelist Are you asking how to recursively print those objects as well or just determine if there are objects?

Comment: This is one of the best answers out there when it comes to a quick debug. Thanks @John

Comment: Essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/32635523/2707864

Comment: `print(self.__dict__)`  works as well. Specially useful when debugging the code without `__repr__` and `__str__`  are defined by the class author.

Answer (score 82):

A generic way that can be applied to any class without specific formatting could be done as follows:

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, symbol, number):
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__class__) + ": " + str(self.__dict__)
```

And then,

```
elem = Element('my_name', 'some_symbol', 3)
print(elem)
```

produces

```
__main__.Element: {'symbol': 'some_symbol', 'name': 'my_name', 'number': 3}
```

Answer (score 21):

A prettier version of response by @user394430

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, symbol, number):
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.__class__) + '\n'+ '\n'.join(('{} = {}'.format(item, self.__dict__[item]) for item in self.__dict__))

elem = Element('my_name', 'some_symbol', 3)
print(elem)
```

Produces visually nice list of the names and values.

```
<class '__main__.Element'>
name = my_name
symbol = some_symbol
number = 3
```

An even fancier version (thanks Ruud) sorts the items:

```
def __str__(self):
    return  str(self.__class__) + '\n' + '\n'.join((str(item) + ' = ' + str(self.__dict__[item]) for item in sorted(self.__dict__)))
```

Comment: return ','.join(('{} = {}'.format(item, self.__dict__[item]) for item in self.__dict__))     .........puts everyting on one line. I removed the class name, I just wanted to print the values for purpose of debugging

Answer (score 20):

Simple. In the print, do:

```
print(foobar.__dict__)
```

as long as the constructor is

```
__init__
```

Comment: Partially interesting. It's fast and "builtin" but is limited to basic value type. A new class object inside will display the class type not the content. So helpfull and interesting too use but not exhaustive compare to the request like _str__ and __repr__ do.

Answer (score 16):

For Python 3:

If the specific format isn't important (e.g. for debugging) just inherit from the Printable class below.  No need to write code for every object.

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23851642/635906) answer

```
class Printable:
    def __repr__(self):
        from pprint import pformat
        return "<" + type(self).__name__ + "> " + pformat(vars(self), indent=4, width=1)

# Example Usage
class MyClass(Printable):
    pass

my_obj = MyClass()
my_obj.msg = "Hello"
my_obj.number = "46"
print(my_obj)
```

Comment: this looks funky when values have spaces...

Comment: `print(vars(obj))` -> good enough for me, thanks

Answer (score 14):

Just to add my two cents to @dbr's answer, following is an example of how to implement this sentence from the official documentation he's cited:

> "[...] to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(), [...]"

Given this class definition:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return "An instance of class Test with state: a=%s b=%s" % (self._a, self._b)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Test("%s","%s")' % (self._a, self._b)
```

Now, is easy to serialize instance of `Test` class:

```
x = Test('hello', 'world')
print 'Human readable: ', str(x)
print 'Object representation: ', repr(x)
print

y = eval(repr(x))
print 'Human readable: ', str(y)
print 'Object representation: ', repr(y)
print
```

So, running last piece of code, we'll get:

```
Human readable:  An instance of class Test with state: a=hello b=world
Object representation:  Test("hello","world")

Human readable:  An instance of class Test with state: a=hello b=world
Object representation:  Test("hello","world")
```

But, as I said in my last comment: more info is just [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/68269)!

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `__repr__`. This is a standard function like `__init__`.
For example:

```
class Foobar():
    """This will create Foobar type object."""

    def __init__(self):
        print "Foobar object is created."

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Type what do you want to see here."

a = Foobar()

print a
```

Comment: __repr__ and __str__ have different semantics:  __repr__ should be Python source that would (re-)create the same object -- this is its *repr*esentation in code ; __str__ should be a pretty userland stringification of the object.

Answer (score 9):

`__repr__` and `__str__` are already mentioned in many answers. I just want to add that if you are too lazy to add these magic functions to your class, you can use [objprint](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/objprint). A simple decorator `@add_objprint` will help you add the `__str__` method to your class and you can use `print` for the instance. Of course if you like, you can also use `objprint` function from the library to print any arbitrary objects in human readable format.

```
from objprint import add_objprint

class Position:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

@add_objprint
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Alice"
        self.age = 18
        self.items = ["axe", "armor"]
        self.coins = {"gold": 1, "silver": 33, "bronze": 57}
        self.position = Position(3, 5)

print(Player())
```

The output is like

```
<Player
  .name = 'Alice',
  .age = 18,
  .items = ['axe', 'armor'],
  .coins = {'gold': 1, 'silver': 33, 'bronze': 57},
  .position = <Position
    .x = 3,
    .y = 5
  >
>
```

Answer (score 6):

Even though this is an older post, there is also a very convenient method introduced in [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (as of Python 3.7). Besides other special functions such as `__eq__` and `__hash__`, it provides a `__repr__` function for class attributes. You example would then be:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
@dataclass
class Test:
    a: str = field(default="foo")
    b: str = field(default="bar")

t = Test()
print(t) 
# prints Test(a='foo', b='bar')
```

If you want to hide a certain attribute from being outputted, you can set the [field](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) decorator parameter `repr` to `False`:

```
@dataclass
class Test:
    a: str = field(default="foo")
    b: str = field(default="bar", repr=False)

t = Test()
print(t) 
# prints Test(a='foo')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are already a lot of answers in this thread but none of them particularly helped me, I had to work it out myself, so I hope this one is a little more informative.

You just have to make sure you have parentheses at the end of your class, e.g:

```
print(class())
```

Here's an example of code from a project I was working on:

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, symbol, number):
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.number = number
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {}\nAtomic Number: {}\n".format(self.name, self.symbol, self.number

class Hydrogen(Element):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name = "Hydrogen", symbol = "H", number = "1")
```

To print my Hydrogen class, I used the following:

```
print(Hydrogen())
```

Please note, this will not work without the parentheses at the end of Hydrogen. They are necessary.

Hope this helps, let me know if you have anymore questions.