# How can I choose a custom string representation for a class itself (not instances of the class)?

Tags: python, class

Consider this class:

```
class foo(object):
    pass
```

The default string representation looks something like this:

```
>>> str(foo)
"<class '__main__.foo'>"
```

How can I make this display a custom string?

---

<sub>See [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327) for the corresponding question about instances of the class.</sub>

<sub>In fact, this question is really a special case of that one - because in Python, classes are themselves also objects belonging to their own class - but it's not directly obvious how to apply the advice, since the default "class of classes" is pre-defined.</sub>

Answer (score 344, accepted):

Implement [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) or [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) in the class's metaclass.

```
class MC(type):
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'Wahaha!'

class C(object):
  __metaclass__ = MC

print(C)
```

Use `__str__` if you mean a readable stringification, use `__repr__` for unambiguous representations.

#### Edit: Python 3 Version

```
class MC(type):
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'Wahaha!'

class C(object, metaclass=MC):
    pass


print(C)
```

Comment: I would like to create some kind of class decorator, so I can easily set custom string representations for my classes without having to write a metaclass for each of them. I am not very familiar with Python's metaclasses, so can you give me any pointers there?

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be done with class decorators; it must be set when the class is defined.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: You could add a string like `_representation` to the class body and `return self._representation` in the `__repr__()` method of the metaclass.

Comment: @BjörnPollex You might be able to pull this of with decorator, but I'd expect you have to struggle with a lot of subtleties of the language. And even if you do you're still bound to use metaclass in one way or another since you don't want to use the default `__repr__` to represent `C`. An alternative to having a `_representation` member is to create a metaclass factory that produces a metaclass with the proper `__repr__` (this could be nice if you're using this a lot).

Comment: This doesn't work with Python 3, any idea how to do it?

Comment: @ThomasLeonard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013249/metaclass-in-python3-5

Comment: So, `repr(x)` does not actually call `x.__repr__()`, but instead calls `x.__class__.__repr__(x)`? This seems to me a very special case in Python.

Answer (score 37):

```
class foo(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "representation"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"representation"
```

Comment: This changes the string representation for `instances` of the class, not for the class itself.

Comment: sorry, doesnt see second part of your post. Use method above.

Comment: @RobertSiemer Why? While his answer is not specifically targeting the OP's question, it's still helpful. It helped me. And at a glance, I don't see any question asking for instance implementation. So probably people land on this page first.

Answer (score 26):

If you have to choose between `__repr__` or `__str__` go for the first one, as by default implementation `__str__` calls `__repr__` when it wasn't defined.

Custom Vector3 example:

```
class Vector3(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.x = args[0]
        self.y = args[1]
        self.z = args[2]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vector3([{0},{1},{2}])".format(self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def __str__(self):
        return "x: {0}, y: {1}, z: {2}".format(self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

In this example, `repr` returns again a string that can be directly consumed/executed, whereas `str` is more useful as a debug output.

```
v = Vector3([1,2,3])
print repr(v)    #Vector3([1,2,3])
print str(v)     #x:1, y:2, z:3
```

Comment: While your point about `__repr__` vs `__str__` is correct, this doesn't answer the actual question, which is about class-objects, not instances.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, completely overseen that. Let me review my answer.

Comment: I think you implementations for repr and str are swapped.

Answer (score 10):

[Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4932473/240490) is quite right. It is, however, from the Python 2 generation. An update for the now-current Python 3 would be:

```py
class MC(type):
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'Wahaha!'

class C(object, metaclass=MC):
    pass

print(C)
```

If you want code that runs across both Python 2 and Python 3, the [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/) module has you covered:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from six import with_metaclass

class MC(type):
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'Wahaha!'

class C(with_metaclass(MC)):
    pass

print(C)
```

Finally, if you have one class that you want to have a custom static repr, the class-based approach above works great. But if you have several, you'd have to generate a metaclass similar to `MC` for each, and that can get tiresome. In that case, taking your metaprogramming one step further and creating a metaclass factory makes things a bit cleaner:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from six import with_metaclass

def custom_class_repr(name):
    """
    Factory that returns custom metaclass with a class ``__repr__`` that
    returns ``name``.
    """
    return type('whatever', (type,), {'__repr__': lambda self: name})

class C(with_metaclass(custom_class_repr('Wahaha!'))): pass

class D(with_metaclass(custom_class_repr('Booyah!'))): pass

class E(with_metaclass(custom_class_repr('Gotcha!'))): pass

print(C, D, E)
```

prints:

```
Wahaha! Booyah! Gotcha!
```

Metaprogramming isn't something you generally need everyday—but when you need it, it really hits the spot!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to all the fine answers, my version with decoration:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import six

def classrep(rep):
    def decorate(cls):
        class RepMetaclass(type):
            def __repr__(self):
                return rep

        class Decorated(six.with_metaclass(RepMetaclass, cls)):
            pass

        return Decorated
    return decorate


@classrep("Wahaha!")
class C(object):
    pass

print(C)
```

stdout:

```sh
Wahaha!
```

The down sides:

1. You can't declare `C` without a super class (no `class C:`)
2. `C` instances will be instances of some strange derivation, so it's probably a good idea to add a `__repr__` for the instances as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, with:

- decorator
- types (so you keep auto-complete in IDEs)
- works as of v3.10

```py
import typing


class ClassReprMeta(type):
    def __repr__(self):
        attrs_str = ", ".join(
            f"{key}={getattr(self, key)}"
            for key in dir(self)
            if not key.startswith("_")
        )

        return f"{self.__name__}({attrs_str})"


T = typing.TypeVar("T")


def printable_class(cls: T) -> T:
    """Decorator to make a class object printable"""
    return ClassReprMeta(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))


@printable_class
class CONFIG:
    FIRST = 1
    SECOND = 2


print(CONFIG)  # CONFIG(FIRST=1, SECOND=2)
```

Comment: Q: Is there a way to coerce the value to be More string-like ... for the case of passing as a Key into dictionary: d[CONFIG] => KeyError. EXAMPLE, building on yours @David: d = {"CONFIG": 456};print(d[str(CONFIG)]);print(d[CONFIG])  Run this. The str() version is ok, and the next excepts, so I currently workaround and do d[str(CONFIG)]. I am just hacking my way and wonder if there is a better way to represent nested, name-checked symbols mapped to strings (which sometimes differ from the names in my case).

Comment: I'm not sure, but remember that dictionary keys don't need to be strings, they can be anything hashable (e.g. tuples). So perhaps just a tuple of your config values will work as a key.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a metaclass to do this, but you need the metaclass itself to have a parameter, you can do it with a metaclass that captures the name via lexical scope.

I find this a bit easier to read / follow than some of the alternatives.

```
class type_: pass

def create_type(name):
    # we do this so that we can print the class type out
    # otherwise we must instantiate it to get a proper print out
    class type_metaclass(type):
        def __repr__(self):
            return f'<{name}>'

    class actual_type(type_, metaclass=type_metaclass):
        pass
    return actual_type

my_type = create_type('my_type')

print(my_type)
# prints "<my_type>"
```