# Using singleton classes in domain model traversal in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, traversal, magic-methods

I'm getting started with Pyramid, and am excited about traversal as a routing strategy. It seems natural and powerful. However, my thinking has led me down a questionable path. Can you suggest a better pattern?

I'm trying to implement a few RESTful routes. For example, I'd like to map the following:

- GET /users -> **index**
- GET /users/chris -> **show**
- GET /users/new -> **new**
- POST /users -> **create**
- PUT /users/chris -> **update**
- DELETE /users/chris -> **destroy**

It seems like the final context of the **show** and **update** actions ought to be the appropriate instance of User, but what about **index** and **create**? It seems like the User class itself would be an appropriate context, however the traversal mechanism, the **__*getitem*__** method, can't be implemented on classes without some metaclass magic. It seemed like there might be a cleaner way to do this. Obviously I could create a UserResourceContainer whose only job would be to handle traversal, but I'm attracted to the elegance of using the User class. Thoughts?

Comment: How do you plan to implement the /users resource without describing it as some sort of container? That seems like the most obvious solution to me. As far as "metaclass magic" goes I'm afraid I don't follow, you can add a `__getitem__` method to any class definition, you just can't add it to an object instance dynamically without some trickery, but that's rare that you would want to do that.

Comment: I was considering using the User class (as a singleton) as the container. The difficulty is that implementing __getitem__ as a class method (with the @classmethod decorator) is [not trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406519/iterating-class-object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that you need a context for the views that map to `/users`. Having a single `User` class would make it quite difficult, and certainly not elegant.

My guess is that a separate `UserContainer` would be the simpler solution you can find. Depending on you database backend, you might even be able to do it in a generic way. For example, with SqlAlchemy:

```
class Container:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            id = int(item)
            return DBSession.query(self.cls).filter_by(id=id).one()
        except (NoResultFound, ValueError):
            raise KeyError(item)
```

Then, your `UserContainer` is just:

```
class UserContainer(Container):
    cls = User
```

Elegant, isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah, I'll go with a separate container. Coming from MVC, I found the separation of model logic from its use in the webapp a familiar pattern. I guess I was just intrigued by the possibility of the models fully supporting traversal on their own. After all, your Container's __getitem__ is very similar to a `User.find({'name': 'chris'})` method one might implement as a class method.

That is a neat trick. I'm using a Mongo backend, but I can still use your idea with a little modification. Thanks!