# String representation of custom data in Racket

Tags: string, scheme, racket, representation

I like how you can retain representation in transparent structs:

```
(struct posn (x y)
        #:transparent)

> (posn 1 2)
(posn 1 2)
```

But is there a way to customize it? Like in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the `prop:custom-write` property [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html?q=prop:custom-write#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._prop~3acustom-write%29%29).  Here's a simple implementation:

```
(struct pr (x y)
  #:transparent
  #:property prop:custom-write (λ (v p w?)
                                 (fprintf p "<~a,~a>" (pr-x v) (pr-y v))))

> (pr 1 2)
<1,2>
```

Note that this works with non-`#:transparent` structures as well.