# IPython representation of classes

Tags: python, ipython, metaclass

I was trying IPython with a module I created and it does not show the actual representation of class objects. Instead it shows something like

```
TheClass.__module__ + '.' + TheClass.__name__
```

I **heavily** use metaclasses in this module and I have really meaningful class representations that should be shown to the user.

Is there an IPython specific method I can change to make the right representation available instead of this namespace thingy that is quite useless in this application?

Or, if that's not possible, how can I customize my version of IPython to show the information I want?

---

EDIT

As complementary information, if I get a class and change the `__module__` attribute to e.g. None, it blows with this traceback when trying to show the representation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ... [Huge traceback] ...
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py", line 599, in _type_pprint
    name = obj.__module__ + '.' + obj.__name__
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

So my expectations were right and this function is used to show class objects:

```
def _type_pprint(obj, p, cycle):
```

I tried customizing it in my class but I don't think I'm doing it right. This module `IPython.lib.pretty` does have a big dictionary linking `type` (the parent of metaclasses) with this function.

---

EDIT 2

Things I tried:

1. Adding the `_repr_pretty_` function to metaclass. It do work with instances but not with classes...
2. Using this function [`IPython.lib.pretty`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html)`.for_type(typ, func)`. It only changes the big dictionary a wrote above but not the copy of it made by the `RepresentationPrinter` instance... So this function has no use at all?!
3. Calling the magic function `%pprint`. It disables (or enables) this pretty print feature, using the default Python `__repr__` for all the objects. That's bad because the pretty printing of lists, dict and many others are quite nice.

The first approach is more of what I want because it does not affect the environment and is specific for this class.

Comment: What do you mean by "representation"?  Do you mean you have a `__repr__` on your class and it isn't being called?

Comment: @BrenBarn: [On the metaclass.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4932438/20862)

Comment: @BrenBarn I have a `__repr__` in the **metaclass** and it does not call it like a normal python shell

Comment: At least #2 of what you tried sounds like it might be a bug, and possibly #1 as well. If you think so, please [file an issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues).

Comment: @ThomasK [I did](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2379) and looks like #1 is a bug in my IPython version but seems to be already corrected in newer versions. Number #2 is not what I want but this seems to be the right behavior... I'll post an answer later after the bug report is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2379) with IPython 0.12 and older versions. Now is possible to do:

```
class A(type):
    def _repr_pretty_(cls, p, cycle):
        p.text(repr(self))

    def __repr__(cls):
        return 'This Information'

class B:   #or for Py3K: class B(metaclass=A):
    __metaclass__ = A
```

and it'll show the desired representation for `B`.