# String representation of a class in Python 3

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, class-variables, representation

I'd like my classes to have a string representation which is based on a class variable (which may be different in derived classes). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4932473/293594) suggests that metaclasses might be the way to go:

```
class MC(type):
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Wahaha!'

class C():
    __metaclass__ = MC

print(C)
```

But this doesn't work in Python 3, returning

```
<class '__main__.C'>
```

instead of `Wahaha!`.
Can someone explain to me what changed between Python 2 and 3 and how to go about it in Python 3?

Comment: Side note: PEP 8 recommends using 4 spaces per indentation, not 2. As a general rule, doing the same thing as virtually everybody else makes life simpler. I did edit your question, so as to not make newcomers believe that it is a good idea to stray away from the standard recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What changed is how the metaclass is declared in 3.x.

```
class C(metaclass=MC):
    pass
```