# Error: <__main__.Node object at 0x03A5F990> while using linked-lists

Tags: python, object, data-structures, linked-list

The following is a linked list implementation using Python:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data,next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class List:
    head=None
    tail=None
    def printlist(self):
        print("list")
        a=self.head
        while a is not None:
                print(a)
                a=a.next

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node(data, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node

p=List()
p.append(15)
p.append(25)
p.printlist()
```

Output:

```
list
<__main__.Node object at 0x03A9F970>
<__main__.Node object at 0x03A9F990>
```

To check your answer you need to edit this inbuilt method `def __repr__` and rewriting it.

You can also do this by adding `__str__` method

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, you should probably [add it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and not edit your question to include the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a custom string representation for a class object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not an error.  You're seeing exactly the output you're asking for: two Node objects.

The problem is that you haven't [defined `__repr__` or `__str__` on your Node class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), and so there's no intuitive way to print out the value of the node objects.  All it can do is punt and give you the default, which is rather unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 13 from

```
print(a)
```

to

```
print(a.data)
```