# How to print class attributes without instantiate an object in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print), I can enumerate instance variable by accessing `str(self.__dict__)`, but I can't figure out how to do that with class variables.

Here's what I want to **AVOID**:

```
# I would like to print out class attributes by overriding `__str__` for that class.
class circle(object):
    radius = 3
    def __str__(self):     # I want to avoid instantiation like this.
        return str(circle.radius)

print(circle())    # I want to avoid instantiation. why can't I just print(circle)?
```

Comment: Related (or dupe?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object

Comment: @Aran-Fey I believe the answer presented in this question are much more clear than answers there. besides, the question is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print(circle())` will call the `__str__` method on an instance of circle.

```
class circle:
  def __str__(self):
    pass
```

as you can see here, you define `__str__` on an instance of circle by using def on the parent class. Therefore you can override the `__str__` method on the CLASS by using ITS parent.

```
 class circle(object):
     class __metaclass__(type):
         def __str__(cls):
             return str(cls.__dict__)
     radius = 3
```

Now, `print circle` will give you

```
{'__module__': '__main__', '__metaclass__': <class '__main__.__metaclass__'>, 'radius': 3, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'circle' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'circle' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

EDIT python3 metaclass syntax

```
class meta(type):
  def __str__(cls):
    return str(cls.__dict__)

class circle(object, metaclass=meta):
  radius = 3
```

Comment: Well at first I thought this is exactly what I want, but there's a minor problem: this code only seem to work on Python2, not Python3.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `__dict__` member of the class object itself (possibly filtering out keys starting with `__`).

```
class circle(object):
    radius = 3

print({k: v for k,v in circle.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('__')}) # prints {'radius': 3}
```

Comment: have you tried your code for yourself? it's throwing SyntaxError.

Comment: Eeh minor typo, coming from writing answers on the phone. There you go.

Comment: @MatteoItalia check this out ;) https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy&hl=en

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke: indeed I already had it installed, and that's how I tried the fix out. :-) I was just too lazy to try it at first (the keyboard input in the REPL is positively horrible).