# Printing __init__ object from list Python error

Tags: python

I am trying to print an object from a list based on my class settings.

```py
from math import *
import time

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

people = [MyClass("David",17),
MyClass("George",63),
MyClass("Zuck",12),
MyClass("Mark",18)
]

print(people[2])
```

But it prints out this:  <**main**.MyClass object at 0x0000000003129128>
I want it to print "Zuck"

Comment: That's the default representation, not an error. What did you want it to print?

Comment: Please update your question to include your *expected* output.

Comment: You haven't told Python how to print your class! This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your array contains objects, so when you print them, they are printed as an object representation. I realize that what you want is to print its content.

For that you have to specify how you want to present the instance when printed, using the method `__str__`:

```
from math import *
import time

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return "name: {}, age: {}".format(self.name, self.age)
```

Comment: I wanted to do that, but i have to wait 4m

Comment: one more question , cannot the last line just be `return "name: {}, age: {}".format(name, age)`

Comment: You can return anything, even a constant like `"Hello"`

Comment: In your case, you'll get an error because `age` and `name` are **instance variables** so they must bu qualified with `self.`. I they where declared in the body of `__str__()`, they could be referenced without self qualified, but they would be different variables than those declared in `__init__()`.

Comment: Oh, yeh i think i got it, im pretty new sorry for my dumbness. thanks