# How to print a global class variable when calling 'print()' on the class (NOT its instance)?

Tags: python

I would like to change the output when I call `print()` on a class (not the instantiation of it!) in Python. I am aware of the `__str(self)__` method for instances. I would like to know its "static" equivalent.

```
class Foo()
    global global_var
    global_var = 2

    def this_is_what_i_need():
        return global_var

print(Foo)

>>> 2
```

EDIT: After a comment from  juanpa.arrivillaga I added `global global_var`

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4932438/3001761

Comment: You need to use a custom metaclass

Comment: Note, a class variable *is not a global variable*. `def this_is_what_i_need(): return global_var` would throw a NameError