# How to print a global class variable when calling 'print()' on the class (NOT its instance) and returning a global variable?

Tags: python, oop

I would like to change the output when I call `print()` on a class (not the instantiation of it!) in Python. I am aware of the `__str(self)__` method for instances. I would like to know its "static" equivalent.

```
class Foo()
    global_var = 2

    # solution code here

print(Foo)

>>> 2
```

This answer is related but does not answer my question because I have a global variable in my class that should be the print output: [How to create a custom string representation for a class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object)

EDIT: After a comment I removed the global declaration of the variable and tried to make my problem clearer

Comment: That's not a "global class variable". That's just a global variable. It's not part of your class at all.

Comment: Use an actual class variable.

Comment: please don't simply re-post the same question as before. It was closed for a reason

Comment: the reason it was closed for, this post answering my question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object, did not answer it in my eyes as I don't want to print some specific string but a variable of my class. There was a prompt to open a new question in this case which I did. I also tried to make the question clearer than in the previous post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided (almost) has a solution:

```py
from six import with_metaclass

class _Foo(type):
    global_var = 2
    def __repr__(self):
        return "The global_var is " + str(self.global_var)

class Foo(with_metaclass(_Foo)):
    pass

print(Foo)
# Prints: The global_var is 2
```

Comment: this is not a global variable, and the answer is the same as the link. Also, don't use `six`, python 2 is passed it's official end of life.

Comment: I never said it was a global variable. The **name** of the variable is `global_var`, just like in the question. Also, I don't think it matters if Py2 is past EoL -- it's a generic answer.

Comment: Yes, it officially is since the beginning of 2020.

Comment: Solved my issue, I moved the `global_var` to `Foo` though.

Answer (score 0):

```
  print(Foo.this_is_what_i_need())
```

Or better yet skip function in your class

```
    print(Foo.global_var)
```