# custom __repr__ as a class method for a class derived from Enum

Tags: python, class, enums, metaclass, repr

I have a class which is derived from enum.Enum.
Now **repr** in enum.Enum refers to the member of the enum.Enum not the entire class.

For Example

```
from enum import Enum
class endpoints(Enum):
""" shop """
    shop = 'shop'
    countries = 'countries'
    policies = 'policies'
    
print(endpoints)
```

Result

```
<enum 'endpoints'>
```

What I tried

```
from enum import Enum
class endpoints(Enum):
    shop = 'shop'
    countries = 'countries'
    policies = 'policies/{object_id}'
    @classmethod
    def __repr__(cls):
        return  '\n'.join([str(member.name) + ':' + (member.value) for member in cls.__members__])

print(endpoint)
```

Result

```
<enum 'endpoints'>
```

This indicates that **repr** is effectively  endpoints.member.**repr**
what I need is endpoint.**repr**?

I understand this can be achieved by a metaclass [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4932473/8277802), but since Enum itself has a metaclass, I cannot inherit/assign from another metaclass.

stopping short of modifying enum.Enum how can I achieve my objective.

The desired output is as follows.

```
print(endpoints)
shop : shop
countries : countries 
policies : policies/{object_id}
```

Comment: Your [mre] has syntax errors. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @wwii fixed the errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To modify a the way a class object is printed, like for any object, you need to modify it's classes `__repr__`, i.e. the *metaclass `__repr__`*, not simply decorate `MyClass.__repr__` with `classmethod`. In this case, you need a custom `EnumMeta`:

```
In [1]: from enum import EnumMeta, Enum

In [2]: class CustomEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return '\n'.join([f"{name}: {value}" for name, value in self.__members__.items()])
   ...:

In [3]: class Endpoints(Enum, metaclass=CustomEnumMeta):
   ...:     shop = 'shop'
   ...:     countries = 'countries'
   ...:     policies = 'policies'
   ...:

In [4]: Endpoints
Out[4]:
shop: Endpoints.shop
countries: Endpoints.countries
policies: Endpoints.policies
```

Basically,

> but since Enum itself has a metaclass, I cannot inherit/assign from another metaclass.

Is wrong. You can provide a custom metaclass *if it derives from the bases' metaclass* just fine even if your base class has a metaclass. It *has* to work this way because *all classes have a metaclass*, by default, `type`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass):

> 3.3.3.3. Determining the appropriate metaclass
>
> - if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then `type()` is used;
> - if an explicit metaclass is given and it is not an instance of `type()`,   then it is used directly as the metaclass;
> - if an instance of `type()` is given as the explicit metaclass, or bases are defined, **then the most derived metaclass is used.**
>
> **The most derived metaclass is selected from the explicitly specified metaclass (if any) and the metaclasses (i.e. `type(cls)`) of all
> specified base classes. The most derived metaclass is one which is a
> subtype of all of these candidate metaclasses.**

Emphasis added. So in this simple case of single inheritance, since `CustomEnumMeta` is the most derived metaclass between `CustomEnumMeta` and `EnumMeta`, then it is used as the metaclass.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. You are correct is stating I am wrong. When i tried  the solution with a custom meta class i got a syntax error stating a conflict between my metaclass and the Enum metaclass, since my metaclass was incomplete and could not create an object, deriving from the orignal metaclass is a more sensible solution.

Answer (score 0):

`__repr__` is called only on class instance like `endpoints('shop')` not on class itself.

Alternatively instead of `__repr__` you may use your own class-method like `enum_members(cls)`, then you can call this own method on class itself instead of instance.

Also you have to do `print(repr(obj))` instead of just `print(obj)` to use `__repr__` method. If you want just to `print(obj)` then create `__str__` method instead of `__repr__`.

Instead of `cls.__members__` use `list(cls)` to enumerate all enum-members.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/PCsIwDMbve4rc2iLowZsgePEpVMrWZVhpm5J2gojPPtvNPzkk6S@hX774yFcK22kamDxgGD1YH4kzHEvfGNemVHAfyYacZIVq10CJdKUIexC1ipkYGkNmi6ni32OZRXLWfEbffvOk7oYma9u/lq3DrOex3NTPoMcBtGaMrLU0Ln20azDmkQOIcxDrW7lOnlJm6dF3yOvQelSwArETJX/pvXVjwQMxLARsAGdTnr@@qKaJXGzKqif/pheLSqlpegM)

```
from enum import Enum
class endpoints(Enum):
    shop = 'shop'
    countries = 'countries'
    policies = 'policies/{object_id}'
    @classmethod
    def __repr__(cls):
        return '\n'.join([str(member.name) + ':' + (member.value) for member in list(cls)])

print(repr(endpoints('shop')))
```

Output:

```
shop:shop
countries:countries
policies:policies/{object_id}
```