# How to make the Python str() function work with a custom class?

Tags: python, class, oop, incompatibility

Often, when using a Python Package, I find myself using the `str()` function to convert a package's custom data-type to a string. If I were to try and create a Python Class for a module, how would I add compatibility to str() function for my package's class?
example:

```py
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age, likes, dislikes):
    self.name = name
    self.personality = {
      "likes": likes,
      "dislikes": dislikes
}

bill = Person("bill", 21, ["coding", "etc"], ["interviews", "socialising"])
strBill = str(bill) # This will store: '<__main__.Person object at 0x7fa68c2acac8>' but I want a dictionary containing all of the variables stored in this 'bill' class


print(strBill)
```

Comment: Implement [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).

Comment: Create `__str__` method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a custom string representation for a class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object)

Comment: also have a look at `__repr__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def __str__(self):` will be used when you try to str(my_object). It would also be called in string interpolation such as `f'This is my object: {my_object}'`

`def __repr__(self):` will be used to represent your object in a console

```
>>> class A():
...     def __str__(self):
...             return 'im a string nicely formatted'
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return 'class A object'
...
>>> a = A()
>>> print(a)
im a string nicely formatted
>>> a
class A object
```