# Stuck making a program that appends players to a list via a class

Tags: python, oop

Instead of printing the player variables from the list it prints:

```
[<__main__.Player object at 0x7f95614f4ee0>, <__main__.Player object at 0x7f95614f4f70>, 
 <__main__.Player object at 0x7f9561520400>]
```

Code:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, swaps, points):
        self.player_name = name
        self.player_swaps = swaps
        self.player_points = points

def add_player(players):
    name = input('Enter the new players Name : ')
    swaps = 3
    points = 0
    players.append(Player(name, swaps, points))
    print('Player Added \n')

def playerselector():
    '''Input for players to choose how many players they want.
    Will tell them if not sensible and get them to do it again.
    '''
    valid = False
    while valid is False:
        try:
            num_players = int(input("How many players do you want? (2-5)\n"))
            if num_players >= 2 and num_players <= 5:
                valid = True
            else:
                print("Please choose a number between 2 and 5")
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry that isn't a number")
    return num_players

num_players = playerselector()
players=[]

for x in range(num_players):
    add_player(players)

print(players)
```

Any tips/solutions?

Comment: Those *are* the `Player` objects.  What do you *want* them to look like when you print them?  (Put that in a `__repr__` method.)

Comment: Here's a general coding tip: Read [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and start following it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a custom string representation for a class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-to-create-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-object) - sorry, wrong one. This one is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add player_return function in class:

```
def player_return(self):
    return [self.player_name,self.player_swaps, self.player_points]
```

and call it in add_player()

```
A=Player(name, swaps, points)
players.append(A.player_return())
```

**Ouput**

```
How many players do you want? (2-5)
2
Enter the new players Name : tim
[['tim', 3, 0]]
Player Added

Enter the new players Name : Jerry
[['tim', 3, 0], ['Jerry', 3, 0]]
Player Added
[['tim', 3, 0], ['Jerry', 3, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name, swaps, points):
        self.player_name = name
        self.player_swaps = swaps
        self.player_points = points
    def __repr__(self):
        rep = f'Player({self.player_name}, {self.player_swaps}, {self.player_points})'
        return rep

def add_player(players):
    name = input('Enter the new players Name : ')
    swaps = 3
    points = 0
    players.append(Player(name, swaps, points))
    print('Player Added \n')

def playerselector():
    valid = False
    while valid is False:
        try:
            num_players = int(input("How many players do you want? (2-5)\n"))
            if num_players >= 2 and num_players <= 5:
                valid = True
            else:
                print("Please choose a number between 2 and 5")
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry that isn't a number")
    return num_players


num_players = playerselector()
players=[]

for x in range(num_players):
    add_player(players)

print(players)
```

Output:

```
How many players do you want? (2-5)
 3
Enter the new players Name :  bob
Player Added 

Enter the new players Name :  joe
Player Added 

Enter the new players Name :  tom
Player Added 

[Player(bob, 3, 0), Player(joe, 3, 0), Player(tom, 3, 0)]
```

You can change the `rep` variable in the `__repr__` method to modify the output. You can find out more about `__repr__` and its uses [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__repr__/)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: ok, I added a link to an article that explains what `__repr__` is