# changing how class names are printed in python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to change how my class is printed using `print` instead of the standard `<class [name]>`? Wasn't able to find an attribute that I can override.

Reason I am asking: I have long chain of modules so it gets hard to debug when the class name is printed as `<class a.b.c.d.e.Foo>`. I'd like to print just `Foo` if possible.

Comment: @KellyBundy `print(Foo)` where `Foo` is a class that I defined myself.

Comment: @KellyBundy I know how to get the name of the class. I am asking how to change the way the class's name is printed.

Comment: As an addition to the other question that already mostly answers yours (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/): If you want to have a *reusable* metaclass that does not "hard-code" the printout but prints the class name as you prefer, write the metaclass's `__str__` or `__repr__` function as follows: `def __repr__(self):
    return self.__name__`. Because in the metaclass, `self` refers to your class (`Foo` in your case), and not to its instances. This is because classes are instances of their metaclass (let that sink in).

Answer (score 0):

Override `__repr__`.

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> print(Foo())
<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f7296192da0>
>>> class Foo:
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return "Foo"
...
>>> print(Foo())
Foo
```

Note that converting to an object to a string will call `__str__` *first* and then fall back to `__repr__`

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return "Foo"
...   def __str__(self):
...     return "Foo (string)"
...
>>> f"{Foo()}"
'Foo (string)'
>>> str(Foo())
'Foo (string)'
>>> Foo()
Foo
```

You may also wish to read [How can I choose a custom string representation for a class itself (not instances of the class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932438/how-can-i-choose-a-custom-string-representation-for-a-class-itself-not-instance) for information on changing the representation of a class as opposed to instances of that class.

Comment: I'm asking how to change the way the name of a _class_ is printed, not how an instance is printed. In your example it's the same as trying to change what gets printed out when you call `print(Foo)`