# Python: multiplication override

Tags: python, overriding, operator-keyword

So, I've got a custom class that has a `__mul__` function which works with ints. However, in my program (in libraries), it's getting called the other way around, i.e., `2 * x` where `x` is of my class. Is there a way I can have it use my `__mul__` function for this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just add the following to the class definition and you should be good to go:

```
__rmul__ = __mul__
```

Comment: Note that this won't always be what you want. Suppose you have vector and matrix classes, and you want to define multiplication between them by treating the vector as a 1xN matrix. Matrix multiplication isn't commutative, so you'd need to re-switch the order of arguments.

Answer (score 37):

Implement `__rmul__` as well.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        print '__mul__'
        return other
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        print '__rmul__'
        return other

x = Foo()
2 * x # __rmul__
x * 2 # __mul__
```

Comment: But `x * x` gives: `<__main__.Foo at 0x7f8604be1e50>` How to handle this?

Comment: @Pi also overload `__repr__`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327.