# Python multiply int to instance both ways

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Ok, so I'm creating a Vector class (the mathematical vector, like [1,3]), and I want to multiply an instance of Vector with an int. First, I implemented the `__mul__` method, and it works fine. However, this don't quite solves the problem.

```
a = Vector(4,3)  # Creates a vector, [4,3]
a*4     # This works fine, and prints [16,12]
4*a     # This, however, creates a TypeError (Unsupported operans type(s)).
```

Now, this is useable, but it could be easier to have it work both ways. Is there a way to do this, in the Vector class?

Comment: This is explained in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Comment: This has been solved in another post.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892616/python-multiplication-override][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892616/python-multiplication-override

Answer (score 11, accepted):

your Vector class can provide the [`__rmul__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__) *reflected multiply* method, which is the method used to implement multiplication when the left-hand operand does not support the operation.