# Define method aliases in Python?

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading, overriding, operator-keyword

I have a vector class and I defined the `__mul__` method to multiply a vector by a number.

Here is the `__mul__` method :

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    x = self.x * other
    y = self.y * other
    new = Vector()
    new.set_pos((x, y))
    return new
```

My problem is that I don't know which is which between the number and the vector.
If self is the number, self.x raises an error. (I'm maybe mistaking on this point : Is "other" always a number ?)

So I found here : [Python: multiplication override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892616/python-multiplication-override)
that I could do :

```
__rmul__ = __mul__
```

but how can I do that in a class definition ?

Something like :

```
def __rmul__ = __mul__
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`self` will never be the number in `__mul__()` because the object the method is attached to is not the number, it's the vector, and by definition it's the multiplicand.

`other` will be a number if your object is being multiplied by a number. Or it could be something else, such as another vector, which you could test for and handle.

When your object is the multiplier, `__rmul__()` is called if the multiplicand doesn't know how to handle the operation.

To handle the case in which `__mul__` and `__rmul__` should be the same method, because the operation is commutative, you can just do the assignment in your class definition.

```
class Vector(object):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        pass

    __rmul__ = __mul__
```

Comment: Am I right in concluding that you are doing the assignment in the _init_ method ?

Comment: no, it's in the class definition.

Comment: Ok thanks I googled for an example of this but could not find one. Final question. By putting it in the class definition the method alias assignment has global scope ?

Comment: global as in all instances of that class will have that behavior, yes.

Answer (score 16):

Simply list it as an attribute:

```
__rmul__ = __mul__
```

This is the same way you'd create an alias of a function in a module; creating an alias of a method within a class body works the same.

Answer (score 4):

The point is that in Python, you can tell objects how to multiply themselves by things. That means that

```
a * b
```

could either mean "tell `a` to multiply itself by `b`" or "tell `b` to multiply itself by `a`". In code, that translates to

```
a.__mul__(b)
```

or

```
b.__rmul__(a)
```

Comment: Is there a way to know which one will be called?

Comment: `__mul__` first, then `__rmul__` if that fails.

Comment: better: or "tell b to multiply a by itself (b)". The multiplication operator doesn't have to be commutative.