# Can a Python class apply two-way overloading?

Tags: python, class

I am not sure what to call this so please bear with me.

Right now I have a class / object where I overloaded the multiplication operator `def __mul__(self, secondthing):`and so if I do `myObject * 4` it knows what to do with it.

But it doesn't know what to do if I do `4 * myObject`, the other way around.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__ - *"These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types."*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892616/python-multiplication-override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement [`__rmul__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__).

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations (+, -, *, /, %, divmod(), pow(), **, <<, >>, &, ^, |) with reflected (swapped) operands. These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6892635/953482) related posts suggests that you can just do `__rmul__ = __mul__`, provided the implementations would have been identical anyway.

Comment: Always try to be [DRY](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Create another function and call it in both or possibly call the other overload function directly.