# How to use pprint to print an object using the built-in __str__(self) method?

Tags: python, string, pprint

I have a Python script which processes a .txt file which contains report usage information. I'd like to find a way to cleanly print the attributes of an object using pprint's pprint(vars(object)) function.

The script reads the file and creates instances of a Report class. Here's the class.

```
class Report(object):
    def __init__(self, line, headers):
        self.date_added=get_column_by_header(line,headers,"Date Added")
        self.user=get_column_by_header(line,headers,"Login ID")
        self.report=get_column_by_header(line,headers,"Search/Report Description")
        self.price=get_column_by_header(line,headers,"Price")
        self.retail_price=get_column_by_header(line,headers,"Retail Price")

    def __str__(self):
        from pprint import pprint
        return str(pprint(vars(self)))
```

I'd like to be able to print instances of Report cleanly a-la-pprint.

```
for i,line in enumerate(open(path+file_1,'r')):
    line=line.strip().split("|")
    if i==0:
        headers=line

    if i==1:
        record=Report(line,headers)
        print record
```

When I call

```
print record
```

for a single instance of Report, this is what I get in the shell.

```
{'date_added': '1/3/2012 14:06',
'price': '0',
'report': 'some_report',
'retail_price': '0.25',
'user': 'some_username'}
 None
```

My question is two-fold.

First, is this a good / desired way to print an object's attributes cleanly? Is there a better way to do this with or without pprint?

Second, why does

```
None
```

print to the shell at the end? I'm confused where that's coming from.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: side note in __str__ when you include from pprint import pprint, if you're only using this method once or twice it's fine, but for a commonly used method this module is going to be imported (computationally intense) every time the method is called. I think it might be better to have your modules imported at the top. Also this improves overall performance in python scripts.

Comment: @lukecampbell -- not true about subsequent imports being computationally intensive. When you import, the mechanism looks in a dict in sys.modules to see if it's already loaded. If it is, nothing else is done. Only if it's never been imported does the import mechanism do anything else.

Comment: @bgporter: What if you create another instance of the object?

Comment: See the docs on import: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/import.html "The system maintains a table of modules that have been or are being initialized, indexed by module name. This table is accessible as sys.modules. When a module name is found in this table, step (1) is finished. If not, a search for a module definition is started."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pprint` is just another form of print. When you say `pprint(vars(self))` it prints vars into stdout and returns none because it is a void function. So when you cast it to a string it turns `None` (returned by `pprint`) into a string which is then printed from the initial print statement. I would suggest changing your print to `pprint` or redefine print as print if its all you use it for.

```
def __str__(self):
    from pprint import pprint
    return str(vars(self))

for i,line in enumerate(open(path+file_1,'r')):
    line = line.strip().split("|")
    if i == 0:
        headers = line
    if i == 1:
        record = Report(line,headers)
        pprint record
```

One alternative is to use a formatted output:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "date added:   %s\nPrice:        %s\nReport:       %s\nretail price: %s\nuser:         %s" % tuple([str(i) for i in vars(self).values()])
```

Hope this helped

Comment: While you've diagnosed the failure correctly, the suggested solutions are all pretty clunky; pprint.pformat is much more elegant.

Answer (score 38):

Dan's solution is just wrong, and Ismail's in incomplete.

1. `__str__()` is not called, `__repr__()` is called.
2. `__repr__()` should return a string, as pformat does.
3. print normally indents only 1 character and tries to save lines.  If you are trying to figure out structure, set the width low and indent high.

Here is an example

```
class S:
    def __repr__(self):
        from pprint import pformat
        return pformat(vars(self), indent=4, width=1)

a = S()
a.b = 'bee'
a.c = {'cats': ['blacky', 'tiger'], 'dogs': ['rex', 'king'] }
a.d = S()
a.d.more_c = a.c

print(a)
```

This prints

```
{   'b': 'bee',
    'c': {   'cats': [   'blacky',
                         'tiger'],
             'dogs': [   'rex',
                         'king']},
    'd': {   'more_c': {   'cats': [   'blacky',
                               'tiger'],
                  'dogs': [   'rex',
                              'king']}}}
```

Which is not perfect, but passable.

Answer (score 14):

`pprint.pprint` doesn't return a string; it actually does the printing (by default to stdout, but you can specify an output stream). So when you write `print record`, `record.__str__()` gets called, which calls `pprint`, which returns `None`.  `str(None)` is `'None'`, and that gets `print`ed, which is why you see `None`.

You should use [`pprint.pformat`](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) instead. (Alternatively, you can pass a `StringIO` instance to `pprint`.)

Answer (score 8):

I think [beeprint](https://github.com/panyanyany/beeprint) is what you need.

Just `pip install beeprint` and change your code to:

```
def __str__(self):
    from beeprint import pp
    return pp(self, output=False)
```

Answer (score 5):

For pretty-printing objects which contain other objects, etc. `pprint` is not enough. Try [IPython's lib.pretty](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html), which is based on a Ruby module.

```
from IPython.lib.pretty import pprint
pprint(complex_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anyany Pan way is the best.

Here I share a real case, when I deal with Azure resource

in AWS resources, I can use `pprint` to print the resource detail easily, but it doesn't work with Azure resource. Because they are different types.

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
#from pprint import pprint
from beeprint import pp
import os

# Acquire a credential object using CLI-based authentication.
credential = AzureCliCredential()

# Retrieve subscription ID from environment variable.
subscription_id = os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"]

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()

for vm in vm_list:
  type(vm)
  # pprint(vm) # doesn't work for Azure resource
  pp(vm)
```

output for reference by beeprint

```
<class 'azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine'>
instance(VirtualMachine):
  _attribute_map: {
    'additional_capabilities': {
      'key': 'properties.additionalCapabilities',
      'type': 'AdditionalCapabilities',
    },
    'availability_set': {
      'key': 'properties.availabilitySet',
      'type': 'SubResource',
    },
    'billing_profile': {
      'key': 'properties.billingProfile',
...
```

output by `pprint`

```
<class 'azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine'>
<azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine object at 0x1047cf4f0>
<class 'azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine'>
<azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_12_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachine object at 0x1047cf5b0>
```