# how to print/return a class in python?

Tags: python, class, object, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: How to print a class or objects of class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/python-how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print)

I currently have this code:

```
class Track(object):
    def __init__(self,artist,title,album=None):
        self.artist = artist
        self.title = title
        self.album = album

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + self.artist + self.album
```

Now when I put something like `Track('Kanye West','Roses','Late Registration')` into the terminal I get `<__main__.Track object at 0x10f3e0c50>` How can I get it to return or print the value at that place?

I'm new to programming and especially new to 'object oriented programming', so my question is what exactly is a class? How do I define a function within a class?

Comment: try `str(Track('Kanye West','Roses','Late Registration'))`

Comment: search first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/python-how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print

Comment: I tried searching but I'm still a little confused, I guess I'm looking for an explanation in more everyday words.

Answer (score 10):

You should define `__repr__` method:

```
class Track(object):

    ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('Track(artist=%s album=%s title=%s)' 
                % (repr(self.artist), repr(self.title), repr(self.album)))
```

Now you can see representation of object in terminal:

```
>>> Track('Kanye West','Roses','Late Registration')
Track(artist='Kanye West' album='Roses' title='Late Registration')
```

**Note** that there is a difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` method:

- `__str__` needs to convert an object into a string. Calling: `str(obj)`
- `__repr__` - for its human readable visualization. Calling: `repr(obj)`

When you put into the terminal `obj`, python calls `repr` function automatically. But if you use `print obj` expression, python calls `str` function:

```
>>> obj
...repr of obj here...
>>> print obj
...str of obj here...
```

See [doc](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) for more information.

Comment: `__repr__` should create a valid Python expression to recreate the object. So you should either change your formatting or use `__str__` instead. See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Comment: although this yields the desired result, this is probably not what the OP wanted, and not within the range of the OPs obviously limited python skillset - i think he just wants to know how to print the answer, a simple solution (like mine) is to just "print"

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, but you are forgetting something.

Lets say you have this class:

```
class Bob():
    def __init__(self, hobby):
        self.hobby = hobby
```

In the console you would make a Bob class with a hobby like this:

```
a = Bob("skiing")
```

then to get Bob's hobby you can do:

```
print a.hobby
```

now - back to your problem, you did `Track('Kanye West','Roses','Late Registration')`

you created an object, but you did not assign the object to a variable. so your result is the object itself... you could simply print the object, which will invoke the `__str__` method. so...

```
print Track('Kanye West','Roses','Late Registration')
```

would work, but if you wanted to do it a bit nicer. (for example)

```
a = Track('Kanye West','Roses','Late Registration')
print a.title
print a.artist
print a.album
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this just for debuging purpose to inspect internal values of your object you can do it like this

```
Track('Kanye West','Roses','Late Registration').__dict__
```

It will show you internal data representation as a python dict

Comment: Rather than explicitly accessing `__dict__`, I think it looks a little cleaner to use `vars(name_of_object)`.