# How to format output of methods inside of a class in an efficient way?

Tags: python

I want to write a class with much stuff inside. Right now I want to have **certain options for the output to show data in a disired format**. Im my example a function inside a class should format the output (a former dictionary) as a list. But i really can't figure out how to do it...

here my try:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def return_values_as_list(self,otherfunction):
        data_as_list=[ i for i in otherfunction.values()]
        return data_as_list

    def get_data1_from_db(self):
        self.data= {'1_testkey':'1_testvalue',"1_testkey2":"1_testvalue2"}

    def get_data2_from_db(self):
        self.data= {'2_testkey':'2_testvalue',"2_testkey2":"2_testvalue2"}
        return self.data
```

What i want to have at the end is something like

> ['1_testvalue','1_testvalue2']

when  instantiation looks like the following:

```
testcase = TestClass()
testcase.get_data1_from_db.return_values_as_list()
```

Any help with that? I thought also of hooks...but i dont really know how to do that...

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1535336/1240268

Comment: thanks for the link...how would that look like for this example?...for me and completeness ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your class `get...` methods should be [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) attributes.

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @property
    def get_data1_from_db(self):
        data= {'1_testkey':'1_testvalue',"1_testkey2":"1_testvalue2"}
        return data.values()

    @property
    def get_data2_from_db(self):
        data= {'2_testkey':'2_testvalue',"2_testkey2":"2_testvalue2"}
        return data.values()

testcase = TestClass()
print testcase.get_data1_from_db  # ['1_testvalue', '1_testvalue2']
print testcase.get_data2_from_db  # ['2_testvalue', '2_testvalue2']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def return_values_as_list(self,otherfunction):
    data_as_list= otherfunction().values()
    return data_as_list
```

You were almost there - you just needed to call the function (add parentheses)

Instantiate with:

```
testcase.return_values_as_list(testcase.get_data1_from_db)
```

Comment: hi Steve! Thanks for your answer! But is it possible to have the Dot syntax somehow...that i dont need to call the object inside of the para again?...just a simple .return_values_as_list() or so...? Thanx!