# python custom class operator overloading

Tags: python, class, oop, operator-overloading

suppose I have a class:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name = "default", age = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

I also have a list of Cats:

```
l = [Cat('Joe')]
```

Now I can't call the following:

```
if 'Joe' in l: # the right syntax would be if Cat('Joe') in list
```

Which operator do I need to overload to be able to `identify` objects of class Cat `by` their member variable `name`?

Comment: I guess its the equal operator, where you can check if the other object is of the same instance and it's name property matcheses the current object's name:
`__eq__(self, other):
    #todo check if other is ame type and if name matches self.name`
Defines behavior for the equality operator, ==.
Sorry, I am a C# guy...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define the `__eq__` method, as shown below:

```
class Cat:

    def __init__(self, name = "default", age = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.name == other
        elif isinstance(other, Cat):
            return self.name == other.name
```

So that when you run your check:

```
l = [Cat('Joe')]

'Joe' in l
#True
```

Comment: OP should define `__hash__()` as well so that it works with sets/dicts. See [the data model documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: I am sorry, what does isinstance? Why do u need that if statement?

Comment: @gen in this case `isinstance` checks if `other` is a string (`str`) or another `Cat`, to tell `__eq__` what to do in each case...

Comment: I have another question: If I do the following:
`for catname in l: print catname` What would it print the object of class Cat or only the name of the object?

Comment: to print the object you can define `__str__()` as [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1535336/832621)

Answer (score 2):

`__contains__` on `list` objects is implemented by checking for equality, so override `__eq__`:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name = "default", age = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other
```

This works irrespective of ordering because equality checking swaps its arguments when the left side does not support the operation.

If you want it to work with hash-based containers (e.g. `set`, `dict`) you'll have to override `__hash__` as well:

```
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
```