# How to distinguish same int and float elements?

Tags: python, list, floating-point, integer

I got following task: create a function that will receive as argument a list of different elements and return a list of original elements (count of each element in list should be not more than 1). Order of elements should remain. Like below:

```
[1, 1.0, '1', -1, 1] # input
[1, 1.0, '1', -1] # output
```

I tried

```
def original_list(*a):
    b=[]    
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            b.append(i)
return b
```

but got `[1, '1', -1]` in return as `1==1.0` is `True`. So how to force Python to "distinguish" int and float elements of the same value and get correct output list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033852/strict-comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ordering isn't important, just use type and a set comprehension.

```
input = [1, 1.0, '1', -1, 1]

output = [x[0] for x in {(y, type(y)) for y in input}]

print output
```

You can use the same idea to preserve ordering.

```
output = []
output_filter = set()
for y in input:
    if (y, type(y)) not in output_filter:
        output_filter.add((y, type(y)))
        output.append(y)
print output
```

Comment: i figured it was an expanded the answer.

Comment: This assumes the list elements are hashable. `input = [[1], [2]]` won't work for example.

Comment: yes, it looks like he is interested in primitives and not data structures. If he tries it on unhashable data structures it will throw an exception (it won't deceptively give a wrong answer, as an `is` based solution would. And I really wanted to steer him away from an O(n^2) solution, to protect him against large data sets. Finally, this whole question isn't terribly Pythonic, so under the circumstances, this seems the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

A little modification to your solution:

```
def original_list(a):
    b=[]    
    for i in a:
        if i not in b or not isinstance(i,int):
            b.append(i)
    return b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

```
>>> example_list = [1, 1.0, '1', -1, 1, 1.0]
>>> output = []
>>> for item in example_list:
        indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(output) if x==item]
        if not indexes:
            output.append(item)
        elif not filter(lambda index: type(item) == type(output[index]) , indexes):
            output.append(item)
        indexes = []
```

We have an input list and an `output` list which is empty initially. First, we iterate on every `item` of the input list. We calculate the `indexes` of all the elements in the `output` list which are equal to that `item` in the input list.
If the `indexes` list is empty, we append that `item` to the `output` list. Otherwise for every index in the `output` list, we filter out those indexes for which type of the `item` and the type of element in `output` list at that index are same. If the list obtained after filtering is empty, we append the `item` to `output` list otherwise `item` of that type has already been added to the `output` list.

After the iteration, the `output` list is our final list.

`>>> output`
`[1, 1.0, '1', -1]`

This will preserve both the order and also filter out the duplicates leaving out unique values of different types.

Comment: `output.append(p)`
you assign nothing to name `p`

Comment: Sorry, edited the post. It was `item` instead of `p`. Check again.

Comment: The complicated one, but it works:)
By the way, this will only works proper with Python2, as with Python3 it returns same [1, '1', -1]