# How to get the last occurrence of list as output?

Tags: python, list, indexing

Can anyone please explain how to output the rightmost index from several most-same-values indexes in the list?

my function:

```
def last_index(xs,key):
i = 0
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[i] == key:
            if i != len(xs):
                return i            
            else: 
                return 'None'
```

for example,

```
xs = [3,4,5,6,4,4,5]                
key = 4
```

the rightmost index output should be a single 5. But I got all three all them which are index 1,4,5.
Thanks for the help, and sorry I'm totally new.

what if the input as strings like:

```
 xs=[True,True,True,False]
 key = True
```

I believe the output is 2?

Comment: I think question is about counting occurrence of key in list

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890170/how-to-find-the-last-occurrence-of-an-item-in-a-python-list

Comment: @AlokThakur Yes. I read the question too quickly. My mistake. I retracted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple solution should do:

```
def last_index(xs, key):
    index = None
    for i in xrange(len(xs)):
        if xs[i] == key:
            index = i  # override index, result in the rightmost index of key
    return index  # returns None if key is not on the list
```

A more efficient way to do this is by iterating from the end to start and returning the index when key is found, in worst case - key is not found and we will iterate over the entire list.

Check out the more efficient version:

```
def last_index(xs, key):
    index = None
    for i in xrange(len(xs)-1, 0, -1):  # iterate from last item to first
        if xs[i] == key:
            index = i
            break  # found the rightmost index, exit the loop
    return index
```

Notice you should prefer using `xrange` over `range` (unless in `python 3` where `range` equals to `xrange`), also to avoid an edge case when items involve different types see Andriy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672615/503099).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't think about the override!

Comment: @markzzzz you would loop thought list more than needed, traverse in reverse order

Comment: Nice, just want to point you to NOTE#2 within my answer, if you wanted you can point to that moment as your answer is accepted and future views would mainly   be concentrated on your answer )) Have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

You can try a function like this

```
def last_index(xs,key):
    index = -1
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[i] == key:
            index=i           
    if index!=-1:
        return index
    else:
        return "none"
```

This will get the last index that matches your key. If there is none will return "none".

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
def last_index(xs,key):
    index = -1
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[i] != key:
            continue
        else:
            index = i
    return index if index != -1 else 'None'
```

Answer (score 1):

Traverse **xs** in **reverse order** and return first matched value, with [**reversed**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) function:

```
def last_index(xs,key):
    for i in reversed(range(len(xs))):
        if xs[i] == key:
            return i


xs = [3,4,5,6,4,4,5]
key = 4
print last_index(xs, key) # output: 5

xs=[True,True,True,False]
key = True
print last_index(xs, key) # output: 2
print last_index(xs, 2) # output: None
```

**NOTE#1**

You can use `xrange` instead of `range` it would give you better performace and won't be deprecated since python3, see [Should you always favor xrange() over range()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range) for more info.

Your comparison may be improved by replacing

```
if xs[i] == key
```

to

```
if xs[i] == key and type(a) == type(b)
```

**NOTE#2**

To avoid bug when your `1 == True` would return you index of `True` however you wanna index of 1 whicn not exist, compare result for both if conditions when xs and key have values below

```
xs=[True,True,True,False]
key = 1
```

See [Strict comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033852/strict-comparison) for more information about that behaviour.

Comment: Just to note, if he is using python 3 then he has to use range (xrange does not exists anymore in python 3).

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the list and then use `.index()`:

```
index = xs[len(xs) - list(reversed(xs)).index(key)]
```

By the way, in your second list, `True` and `False` are booleans, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate from behind like this:

```
def last_index(xs,key):
    i= len(xs)-1
    while i >=0:
        if xs[i] == key:
            return i
         i -= 1
```

This way if the key does not exist the function will return the none value