# How does parenthesis change whether or not the output will be true or false?

Tags: python

The question was this in my python beginners course
Add a pair of parentheses to each expression so that it evaluates to True.
0 == 1 == 2

And the answer given was ( 0 == (1==2))
Isnt it still false in the answer too as 1 is not equals to 2 and 0 is not equal to any of them

Comment: `0 == False` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033852/strict-comparison

Comment: `(0 == (1==2))` evaluates to `(0 == False)`, which in Python is True.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764017/is-false-0-and-true-1-an-implementation-detail-or-is-it-guaranteed-by-the. I don't have the final hammer for this tag :/

Comment: That ^ is a far better dupe target

Comment: @trincot Thanks for digging that up; added as the primary dupe.

Answer (score 5):

```
0 == 1 == 2
```

This is a chained comparison, equivalent to

```
0 == 1 and 1 == 2
```

Neither statement is true, so the whole thing is false. This is the behavior you're imagining.

```
0 == (1 == 2)
```

This is *not* a chained comparison. This is a comparison of a number (zero) against a Boolean (`1 == 2`). We know `1 == 2` is false, so this is equivalent to

```
0 == False
```

And, in Python, `0` and `False` are (mostly) synonymous, and crucially they compare equal.

```
True
```