# Retrieving a class object from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

As part of a beginners' university Python project, I am currently creating a database of words, be it Nouns, Verbs, Determiners, Adjectives.

Now the problem I am having is that the words being read into the program via the `lexicon.readfromfile` method are being put into the dictionary via an instance of a class ( be it noun, verb or adjective ). This created the problem that I have absolutely no idea how to call these objects from the dictionary since they do not have variables as keys, but rather memory locations (see the following):

```
{<__main__.Verb object at 0x02F4F110>, <__main__.Noun object at 0x02F4F130>, <__main__.Adjective object at 0x02F4F1D0>, <__main__.Noun object at 0x02F4F170>}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can call these keys in such a way that I can make them usable in my code?

Here is the part I'm stuck on:

> Add a method `getPast()` to the `Verb` class, which returns the past tense of    the `Verb`. Your `getPast()` method can simple work by retrieving the value of ‘past’ from the attributes.

Here is a the majority of the code, leaving out the `Noun` and `Adjective` classes:

```
class Lexicon(object):
    'A container clas for word objects'

    def __init__(self):
        self.words = {}

    def addword(self, word):
        self.words[word.stringrep] = word

    def removeword(self, word):
        if word in self.words:
            del(word)
            print('Word has been deleted from the Lexicon' )
        else:
            print('That word is not in the Lexicon')


    def getword(self,wordstring):
        if wordstring in self.words:
            return self.words[wordstring]
        else:
            return None


    def containsword(self,string):
        if string in self.words:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def getallwords(self):
        allwordslist = []
        for w in self.words:
            allwordslist.append(self.words[w])
        return set(allwordslist)

    def readfromfile(self, x):
        filehandle = open(x, 'r')
        while True:
            line = filehandle.readline()
            if line == '':
                break
            line = line.strip()
            info = line.split(',')
            if info[1] == 'CN' or info[1] == 'PN':
                noun=Noun(info[0],info[1])
                noun.setattribute('regular',bool(info[2]))
                self.addword(noun)
            elif info[1] == 'A':
                adjective=Adjective(info[0],info[1])
                adjective.setattribute('comparative', bool(info[2]))
                self.addword(adjective)
            elif info[1] == 'V':
                verb=Verb(info[0],info[1])
                verb.setattribute('transitive', bool(info[2]))
                verb.setattribute('past', info[3])
                self.addword(verb)




    def writetofile(self, x):
        filehandle = open(x, 'w')

        for t in self.words.values():
            filehandle.write(t.getFormattedString() + '\n')
        filehandle.close()
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#           

class Word(object):
    'A word of any category'

    def __init__(self,stringrep,category):
        self.wordattribute = {}
        self.stringrep = stringrep
        self.category = category

    def setattribute(self, attributename, attributevalue):
        self.wordattribute[attributename] = attributevalue

    def getvalue(self,name):
        if name in self.wordattribute:
            return self.wordattribute[name]
        else:
            return none


    def __str__(self):
        return self.stringrep + ':' + self.category

    def __lt__(self,otherword):
        return self.stringrep < otherword.stringrep

class Verb(Word):
    '"Represents a Verb."'

    def __init__(self, stringrep, category):
        super().__init__(stringrep,category)

    def istransitive(self):
        return self.transitive

    def getFormattedString(self):
        n = '{stringrep},{category}' 
        n = n.format(stringrep=self.stringrep, category=self.category)
        for i in range(1,2):
            for v,b in self.wordattribute.items():
                n = n+','+str(b)
        return n
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1535327/3001761. Also, that appears to be a `set`, not a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `set` there, not a dictionary. A `set` will let you check to see whether a given instance is in the set quickly and easily, but, as you have found, you can't easily get a specific value back out unless you already know what it is. That's OK because that's not what the `set` is for.

With a dictionary, you associate a key with a value when you add it to the dictionary. Then you use the key to get the value back out. So make a dictionary rather than a set, and use meaningful keys so you can easily get the value back.

Or, since I see you are already making a list before converting it to a set, just return that; you can easily access the items in the list by index. In other words, don't create the problem in the first place, and you won't have it.