# Printing and Formatting an Instance

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to Define a **str** method for this class here so that when an instance of class Student is printed, it prints something of the format: My name is ___. I've been in college for __ years and I've written __ programs. Below the correct phrasing is printing but the correct values are not printing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Student():
def __init__(self, name, years_at_umich=1):
    self.name = name
    self.years_UM = years_at_umich
    self.bonus_points = random.randrange(1000)
    self.programs_written = 0
def __str__(self):
    return "My name is %s. I've been in college for %d years and I've written %d programs" \
        %(self.name, self.years_UM, self.programs_written)
def shout(self, phrase_to_shout):
    print phrase_to_shout  

def year_at_umich(self):
    return self.years_UM

def write_programs(self, progs=1):
    self.programs_written += progs
    return self.programs_written
```

---

*** tests for diffrent values, currently it's only passing the last test for student 4********

```
class Student_test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_student1(self):
        student1 = Student("Lyra")
        self.assertEqual(student1.__str__(),"My name is Lyra. I've been at UMich for 1 years and I've written 0 programs.")
    def test_student2(self):
        student2 = Student("Aisha")
        student2.write_programs()
        self.assertEqual(student2.__str__(),"My name is Aisha. I've been at UMich for 1 years and I've written 1 programs.")
    def test_student3(self):
        student3 = Student("Ali",3)
        student3.write_programs(4)
        self.assertEqual(student3.__str__(),"My name is Ali. I've been at UMich for 3 years and I've written 4 programs.")
    def test_student4(self):
        student4 = Student("Aja")
    student4.write_programs(12)
    self.assertEqual(student4.programs_written, 12)
    student4.write_programs()
    self.assertEqual(student4.programs_written,13)
```

Comment: Your ``shout`` method will not print ``phrase_to_shout`` like you expect because it never formats the string but instead overwrites your argument. Similarly, the ``year_at_umich`` method won't return a formatted string.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print) if we assume this question is not about formatting strings, but is instead focused on printing custom strings for an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `__str__()` may be helpful.

For example:

```
import random
class Student():
    def __init__(self, name, years_at_umich=1):
        self.name = name
        self.years_UM = years_at_umich
        self.bonus_points = random.randrange(1000)
        self.programs_written = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return "My name is %s. I've been in college for %d years and I've written %d programs" \
            %(self.name, self.years_UM, self.programs_written)
```

When you print your Student,you will see:

```
>>>test_stu = Student("Mike")
>>>print test_stu

My name is Mike. I've been in college for 1 years and I've written 0 programs
```

And the following links may be helpful:

[https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=**mro**#object.**str**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__mro__#object.__str__)
and
[Difference between **str** and **repr** in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: Great thanks for the help. My program, for the most part, seems to be working, but it's not printing out the correct values. I have edited my original code, if you could take a look that would be great.

Comment: Try to change `return self.programs_written + progs` to ` self.programs_written += progs`.This will add progs to self.programs_written.

Comment: when I change it to return self.programs_written += progs I receive a traceback invalid syntax.

Comment: Don't change it to `return self.programs_written += progs`.If you want to return`self.programs_written`,you can do  `self.programs_written += progs` first and do `return self.programs_written` in the next step.

Comment: Great adding those two lines worked for most of it. However, when I try to test my code for different values it fails.....see updated code with other values that are being tested. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you miss a  `.` after the word `programs` at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Student():
  def shout(num, word):
    if num == 1:
      phrase = "My name is %s" % word
    elif num == 2:
      phrase = "I love %s" % word
    elif num == 3:
      phrase = "My favorite food is %s" % word
    return phrase

  def years(num):
    phrase = "I've been at umich for %s years" % num
    return phrase

  def programs(num):
    phrase = "I've written %s programs" % num
    return phrase
```

> > > Student.shout(1, 'Mud')
> > >       'My name is Mud'

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement method [__str__](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) or [__repr__](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) in class `Student`. If you just need the instance to be printed in your way, `__str__` is enough:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return "My name is {}. I've written {} programs".format(self.name, self.programs_written)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining the `__str__` method for the class, which is called whenever the instance is converted to a string:

```
class Student():
     # insert the same init here

    def shout(self):  # we do not need to ask for name because
                      # we already have it stored in self.name
        phrase = "My name is %."
        return phrase % self.name  # format the text before returning it
        # it's also useful to return the string instead
        # of immediately printing it in this case because
        # we will use it later

    def year_at_umich(self):
        phrase = "I've been at umich for %s years"  # do not modify the instance attribute
        return phrase % self.years_UM  # use it to format your phrase

    def say_number_programs(self):  # keeping in pattern with our previous methods
        phrase = "I've written %s programs"
        return phrase % self.programs_written

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s. %s and %s.' % (self.shout(),              # we can format the final string
                                   self.year_at_munich(),     # during the str call
                                   self.say_number_programs)

st = Student('Bob')

print st
```

This returns

`My name is Bob. I've been at umich for 1 year and I've written 0 programs.`