# Object-oriented programming (python)

Tags: python, oop

```
class Ammo(Thing):
    def __init__(self, name, weapon, quantity):
        self.name=name
        self.weapon=weapon
        self.quantity=quantity
    def get_quantity(self):
        return self.quantity
    def weapon_type(self):
        return self.weapon
    def remove_all():
        self.quantity=0

bow = Weapon('bow', 10, 20)
arrows = Ammo('arrow', bow, 5)
print(arrows.weapon_type())
```

output of `print(arrows.weapon_type())` is supposed to be `bow` but I got `<__main__.Weapon object at 0x10441f0b8>` instead. How can I modify my code so that it returns `bow`?

Below is `class Weapon`:

```
import random
class Weapon(Thing):
    def __init__(self, name, min_dmg, max_dmg):
        self.name=name
        self.min_dmg=min_dmg
        self.max_dmg=max_dmg
    def min_damage(self):
        return self.min_dmg
    def max_damage(self):
        return self.max_dmg
    def damage(self):
        return random.randint(self.min_dmg,self.max_dmg)
```

Comment: Try `return self.weapon.name` inside `weapon_type`.  You are returning (and then printing) the *entire* `Weapon` object instead of just the name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a class or objects of class using print()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print)

Comment: @RocketHazmat this worked perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do it would be overriding the **str** function in Weapon.

adding:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

to your weapon class should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you want to print.

```
bow = Weapon('bow', 10, 20)
arrows = Ammo('arrow', bow, 5)
print(arrows.weapon_type())
```

The name of object:

```
bow = Weapon('bow', 10, 20)
#               \_______ name of object
```

so you have to:

```
print(arrows.weapon_type().name)
# it will print bow
```

or your object itself:

```
bow = Weapon('bow', 10, 20)
#  \____________________ object
```

I personally prefer print the name I passed in arguments, so if I call  my object `bow` and pass `"hardened_bow", 10, 20` as arguments it will print `"hardened_bow"` and not `"bow"`

Answer (score 0):

Add repr to Weapon class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

**object.__repr__(self)**

Called by the **repr()** built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).

If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines **repr**() but not **str**(), then **repr**() is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.

This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous.

**object.__str__(self)**

Called by the **str()** built-in function and by the print statement to compute the “informal” string representation of an object. This differs from **__repr__()** in that it does not have to be a valid Python expression: a more convenient or concise representation may be used instead. The return value must be a string object.

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)