# How to view and interpret the output of lda model using gensim

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I am able to create the lda model and save it. Now I am trying load the model, and pass a new document

`lda = LdaModel.load('..\\models\\lda_v0.1.model')
doc_lda = lda[new_doc_term_matrix]
print(doc_lda )`

On printing the doc_lda I am getting the object. `<gensim.interfaces.TransformedCorpus object at 0x000000F82E4BB630>`
 However I want to get the topic words associated with it. What is the method I have to use. I was referring to [this](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but have you tried `get_document_topics()`? Though I assume that would only work if you've updated your LDA model using `update()`.

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code - the "Usage example" from the documentation link you posted uses `doc2bow` which returns a sparse vector - I don't know what `new_doc_term_matrix` consists of, but I'll assume it worked fine.

You might want to look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-objects-of-class-using-print): you want to `print` an "object" - that isn't printable, the data you want is somewhere in the object, and that in itself is printable.

Alternatively, you can also use your IDE's capabilities - the Variable explorer in Spyder, for example - to click yourself into the objects and get the info you need.

For more info on similarity analysis with gensim, see [this tutorial](https://markroxor.github.io/gensim/static/notebooks/topic_methods.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use this
`doc_lda.print_topics(-1)`