# Extending AST nodes for python 2.7 compiler module and printing them

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-construction

I'm using the `compiler` module found in python 2.7 to get the abstract syntax tree from a python program, and I want to extend the set of AST nodes with my own nodes.

For example, given the python program `1+2`, when parsed, the AST given from the `compiler` module outputs:

**Parser program:**

```
import compiler
ast = compiler.parse("1+2")
print ast
```

**Output:**

```
Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Add((Const(1), Const(2))))]))
```

Now, I wish to extend the AST library with boolean nodes. Currently the `compiler` module assigns `True`, `False`, as `Name()` nodes. i.e. `compiler.parse("True")` outputs `Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Name('True'))]))`

My plan is to construct a class named `Bool`, and wrap nodes with boolean values, stripping those `Name()` nodes and using my `Bool` nodes instead. My Bool definition.

```
class Bool():
def __init__(self,expr):
    self.expr = expr
```

**Question**, when printing the ast now, after correct substitution, it does not print in the similar style as the other nodes. Instead it gives for

```
compiler.parse("True")
```

It outputs

```
Module(None, Stmt([Discard(<Bool instance at 0x10e4306c8>)]))
```

Instead, what practice can I use to print those `Bool` nodes in similar fashion as how the `compiler` module does? e.g. desire:

```
Module(None, Stmt([Discard(Bool('True'))]))
```

Comment: Implement `__repr__` for your class? This isn’t specific to ASTs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wow! Didn't realize it was that simple! Thanks much!