# Seeing the result of class object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just wrote this class in python to extract some features from a dataset :

```
class Features :

    def __init__ (self , data):
        self.data = data 

    def Energy (self) :
        energy=float (sum(self.data**2))
        return (energy)

    def Power (self):
        power = float (sum(self.data**4))
        return power

    def NonlinearEnergy (self) :
        limit1=0
        NLE = 0
        while limit1 < len(self.data):
            NLE += float ((-self.data[limit1]*self.data[limit1-2] + self.data[limit1-1]**2 ))
            limit1+=1

        return NLE

    def CurveLength (self):
        limit2=0
        CL=0
        while limit2 < len(self.data):
            CL += float ((self.data[limit2] - self.data[limit2-1]))
            limit2+=1
```

and when I try to see the result of a dataset's object, the result appears Like that :

`<bound method Features.Energy of <__main__.Features object at 0x0000028952C105C0>>`

My question is: how can I see the result numerically, or in other words, how can I see my actual result?

Comment: What code do you use to see the result?

Comment: The output you show suggests you're just accessing the `Energy` method, without calling it. Try using `some_feature_object.Energy()` instead of `some_feature_object.Energy` and you should get a float. If you *really* want the computed values to work like attributes, you could instead decorate the methods with `@property`, but I'm not sure that's really necessary here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens as a result of calling a method without brackets.

Take a look at the example:

```
obj = Features(data)
print (obj.Energy())
```

So, first create a new object for your class and then call your method as `obj.Energy()`. This is because, whenever an object calls its method, the object itself is passed as the first argument. So, `obj.Energy()` translates into `Features.Energy(obj)`