# How can we get the default behavior of __repr__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, representation, repr

If someone writes a class in python, and fails to specify their own `__repr__()` method, then a default one is provided for them. However, suppose we want to write a function which has the same, or similar, behavior to the default `__repr__()`. However, we want this function to have the behavior of the default `__repr__()` method even if the actual `__repr__()` for the class was overloaded. That is, suppose we want to write a function which has the same behavior as a default `__repr__()` regardless of whether someone overloaded the `__repr__()` method or not. How might we do it?

```
class DemoClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 4
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.var)

def true_repr(x):
    # [magic happens here]
    s = "I'm not implemented yet"
    return s

obj = DemoClass()

print(obj.__repr__())

print(true_repr(obj))
```

### Desired Output:

`print(obj.__repr__())` prints `4`, but `print(true_repr(obj))` prints something like:
`<__main__.DemoClass object at 0x0000000009F26588>`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `object.__repr__(obj)`. This works because the default `repr` behavior is defined in `object.__repr__`.

Answer (score 20):

Note, the best answer is probably just to use `object.__repr__` directly, as the others have pointed out. But one could implement that same functionality roughly as:

```
>>> def true_repr(x):
...     type_ = type(x)
...     module = type_.__module__
...     qualname = type_.__qualname__
...     return f"<{module}.{qualname} object at {hex(id(x))}>"
...
```

So....

```
>>> A()
hahahahaha
>>> true_repr(A())
'<__main__.A object at 0x106549208>'
>>>
```

Comment: Nifty! Didn't know about `__qualname__`, is it a recent addition?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Relatively recent; `__qualname__` was added in version 3.3: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/

Answer (score 10):

Typically we can use **`object.__repr__`** for that, but this will to the "object repr for *every* item, so:

```
>>> object.__repr__(4)
'<int object at 0xa6dd20>'
```

Since an `int` is an `object`, but with the `__repr__` overriden.

If you want to go up *one* level of overwriting, we can use `super(..)`:

```
>>> super(type(4), 4).__repr__()  # going up one level
'<int object at 0xa6dd20>'
```

For an `int` that thus again means that we will print `<int object at ...>`, but if we would for instance subclass the `int`, then it would use the `__repr__` of `int` again, like:

```
class special_int(int):

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Special int'
```

Then it will look like:

```
>>> s = special_int(4)
>>> super(type(s), s).__repr__()
'4'
```

What we here do is creating a *proxy* object with `super(..)`. Super will walk the *method resolution order (MRO)* of the object and will try to find the first function (from a superclass of `s`) that has overriden the function. If we use single inheritance, that is the closest parent that overrides the function, but if it there is some multiple inheritance involved, then this is more tricky. We thus select the `__repr__` of that parent, and call that function.

This is also a rather weird application of `super` since usually the class (here `type(s)`) is a fixed one, and does *not* depend on the type of `s` itself, since otherwise multiple such `super(..)` calls would result in an infinite loop.

But usually it is a bad idea to break overriding anyway. The reason a programmer overrides a function is to *change the behavior*. Not respecting this can of course sometimes result into some useful functions, but frequently it will result in the fact that the code contracts are no longer satisfied.  For example if a programmer overrides `__eq__`, he/she will also override `__hash__`, if you use the hash of another class, and the real `__eq__`, then things will start breaking.

Calling magic function directly is also frequently seen as an *antipattern*, so you better avoid that as well.

Comment: The issue here is that the intuitive concept of "the default `__repr__`" may not really mean what the questioner wants it to mean. (Also, I would normally downvote anything that suggests passing the output of `type` to `super`, but it may make sense here. It needs more warnings about grandchild classes, though.)