# Python: How to add __str__ for functions

Tags: python, function

When I printed my function (without the function call),

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred): 
    return backend.sum(backend.abs(y_true - y_pred))
```

I got something like

```
<function __main__.loss>
```

I need it to return a string like

```
Absolute Error Sum
```

Most [links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535327/3125070) I looked at explain how to do the same for class objects. How do I define what string the **function** should return?

Comment: You can't, `__str__` is looked up on the type.

Comment: Are you sure you it to return that string? That is the sort of info that usually goes in a docstring.

Comment: Convert it to class.

Comment: Yes, convert it to a class. Implement `__call__` method to make the instance callable, override `__repr__` to customize the output.

Comment: Could even use the class as a decorator for a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to edit the `__name__` attribute of it:

```
>>> def f(x): print(x)

>>> f
<function f at 0x7feb2c843a28>

>>> f.__name__ = 'my function'

>>> f
<function my function at 0x7feb2c843a28>

>>> f.__name__
my function
```

Edit: note that in Python 3, you may have to overwrite the `__qualname__` property instead (see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/ and https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5566/).

Comment: but if i need to import this function to many other files, how do I do it?

Comment: is it possible to edit this attribute inside of the function itself using something like `self.__name__ == mystr`???

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to edit the name within the definition of the function itself.  However, if you put the `__name__` definition at the same place that the function is defined, it should run whenever the function is imported.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. works as long as I'm doing that in the current file

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you will have to use `__qualname__` instead (see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5566/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the default `repr` of the function type, but you can extract the part you care about and format it however you want.

For example, if you want a friendlier name, the actual name is stored in `__name__`, so you could `print(loss.__name__)` if you want to avoid the extra wrapping. This isn't perfect (`lambda` functions don't have names for instance), but it's better than trying to rewrite the default `repr` for functions.