# Change print function in python objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a list A of instances of a certain class. I want to change what returns when I do `print(A)`.

```
A = [MyClass(i) for i in range(10)]
print(A)
[<__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808a2b0>,
 <__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808a320>,
 <__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808a780>,
 <__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808a7f0>,
 <__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808a860>,
 <__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808a710>,
 <__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808a940>,
 <__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808a8d0>,
 <__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808ada0>,
 <__main__.MyClass at 0x7f286808ad30>]
```

I would rather maybe had as return something like

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to implement `__repr__` function under your MyClass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a class or objects of class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `__repr__` method inside `MyClass`, obtaining something like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.i)

print([MyClass(i) for i in range(3)]) # prints '[0, 1, 2]'
```

Comment: That's wrong. Implementing `__str__` still won't change the output, since when you call print on a container it prints the objects `__repr__`

Comment: Yes, and your code works because you print `MyClass` object. If you put it inside a container like the OP question, you will see it won't work. Try this: `a = [MyClass(3)]; print a`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to change the default representation of an object. This is done by implementing the `__repr__` function.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.i)


>>> A = [MyClass(i) for i in range(3)]
>>> print A
[0, 1, 2]
```

When you call `print` on an object, the object executes `__str__`. Since `A` is a list (container), the container executes each object `__repr__` function instead.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for an isolated task, you can retrieve the argument as part of a list comprehension:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

A = [MyClass(i) for i in range(10)]

print([x.var for x in A])

# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Otherwise, as [demonstrated by @Vinny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49719009/9209546), you can add a `__repr__` method to your class.