# Difference between urlopen.(url) and requests.get(url)

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urlopen

My code:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p')
t = urlopen('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p')

print(r)

'Response [200]'

print(t)

'http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x0430A370'
```

Why does requests.get only return the object instance (in this case the respond code) while urlopen returns the actual object?

My question then would be: how can I use requests to return an object instead of the response code? (I want to desearialize the content using pickle)

Comment: What an object does with a `print(x)` call doesn't completely encompass what has actually been "returned " to `x`.

Comment: You're a bit confused about what 'object instance' means.  It is the same thing as 'actual object'.  What you meant to say is that it appears to return the response code rather than the response object.  However, that's just due to the way the response class's string conversion function works.  Note that the requests response object is a different class than the http.client.HHTResponse object returned by urlopen.  They both represent a response, but using different object classes.

Comment: To get a better idea of what is being returned (print-debugging python), use `from pprint import pprint` and `pprint(r)`

Comment: @JeffLearman `pprint` is a great suggestion, though in this particular case it will just return the response code again. It would be more helpful to do `pprint(vars(r))`

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing what is returned by `print` with the object itself. `requests.get` *does* get the object. The developer of `requests` made the executive decision to return `r.status_code` when you call the `print` function. They could have returned anything: `r.text`, or `r.raw`, for example. It sounds like you were expecting to see the latter.

If you're interested, here is a bit more information about how developers can define what print returns: [How to print a class or objects of class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print)