# Python - How to print a list's contents that have class objects inside?

Tags: python, list, class, oop, object

I'm new in Python, and didn't find a similar previous question here. 
My question is how can I see the real contents of the list `node_list` here, instead the memory address?? (which actually includes node1, node2 names and its neighbors)

```
class node:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name=name
    self.neighbors={}

  def update(self, name, weight):
    if name in self.neighbors:
      self.neighbors[name]=max(int(weight),int(self.neighbors[name]))
    elif self.name==str(name):
      print ("this is prohibited to add a key name as an existed name")
    else:
      self.neighbors[name] = str(weight)

node_list = []

node1 = node('1')
node_list.append(node1)
node1.update('2',10)
node1.update('4',20)
node1.update('5',20)

node2 = node('2')
node_list.append(node2)
node2.update('3',5)
node2.update('4',10)

print(node1.name)        #  That's OK - prints:  1
print(node1.neighbors)   #  That's OK - prints:  {'2': '10', '4': '20', '5': '20'}
print(node_list)         #  Not OK: prints:[<__main__.node object at 0x7f572f860860>, <__main__.node object at 0x7f572f860dd8>]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to create a `__str__` method for nodes inside their class definition. Otherwise, Python automatically prints the memory address.

Here is a similar question.

[How to print a class or objects of class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-a-class-or-objects-of-class-using-print)

Comment: Thanks, but I already have seen this answer, but it's not related to a list contents. Is the implementation should be different ?  what should I write in __str__ method that makes it work (print(node_list)) ?

Comment: You need to define the __repr__() command. Calling the str command on a list returns a string composed of calling the repr command on all the objects that the list contains, so you would need to make the __repr__() command the same as your string command. Hopefully, this works. Sorry for the initial misleading comment. @Eli