# What's the significance of these Python class method outputs?

Tags: python, class

Imagine we have a class with three methods defined:

```py
class MyClass:

    def instance_method(self):
        return "Instance method called", self

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        return "Class method called", cls

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        return "Static method called"
```

We instantiate it and call the instance method:

```
obj1 = MyClass()
obj1.instance_method()
# --> ('Instance method called', <__main__.MyClass at 0x106634588>)
```

And then we call the class method:

```
obj1.class_method()
# --> ('Class method called', __main__.MyClass)
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the instance method is bracketed by '<>', and why it contains a pointer to a location in memory when the class method does not.

Comment: Because the default `repr` of an instance is different to the default `repr` of a class. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535327/3001761

Comment: On python3.7 these two respectively prints: `<__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f1e9468a160>` and `<class '__main__.MyClass'>`.

Comment: Ditto for Python 2.7, whether `MyClass` is an old-style or new-style class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I called the .__repr__ attribute on the class and the instance and I see what you mean. Would it be accurate to say this is a formatting difference and mostly immaterial?

Comment: You appear to be using IPython, or a Jupyter notebook or something else backed by IPython. This is something you should always mention when asking questions, as IPython does a lot of custom handling that regular Python doesn't.

Comment: `__repr__` isn't actually being used here. You're seeing IPython's custom printing logic.

Comment: @user2357112 An excellent suggestion, I'll do that moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

All three serve for different purposes. But let's start with this:

```
class MyClass:
    def method(x):
        return "method called", x
```

when you have an instance `y = MyClass()` and call `y.method()`, what do you expect for `x` in the function?

- If you want `x` to be the object `y`, it is the instance method;
- If you want that to be not `y` but the class of `y`, it is the class method (remember you cannot check anything specific to `y` any more, only the stuff generic for the whole class is allowed); and
- If you want that to be nothing -- you do not even need to know the object `y` inside the function, nor the class of `y`, and hence `x` should not even exist -- that will be a best fit for static method. We usually use static method for things normally a function can do but try to wrap it under a class so it does not pollute the global name space.

Comment: This is a good explanation, my question was just about why the instance and class methods had different outputs (answer: their __repr__ attributes are different by default)