# i am setting python class but it prints <main.deteil object at 0x03391d90

Tags: python

i am setting python class but it prints <**main**.deteil object at 0x03391d90

i tried to search in google but didn't helped me

Python classes

```
class person:
    def __init__(self,fname,lname):
        self.firstname = fname
        self.lastname = lname

    def printname(self):
        print(self.firstname, self.lastname)

class student(person):
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,year):
        person.__init__(self,fname,lname)
        self.graduate_year = year

    def welcome(self):
        print("Welcome", self.firstname, self.lastname, self.graduate_year)

class dateils(person):
    def __init__(self,fname,lname, age, gender,):
        person.__init__(self, fname, lname)
        self.age = 17
        self.gender = "male"

    def student_details(self):
        print(self.firstname, self.lastname, self.age,self, self.gender)


#Student
x = student("Enter your name:", "Enter your lastname: ", 2019)

x.welcome()

#person details
d = dateils(input("Enter your name"), input("Enter your lastname"), input("Enter your age"), input("Enter your gender"))
d.student_details()
```

i expected the output of details to be entered info, but the actual output is 
entered name, entered lastname, entered age, and this <**main**.dateils object at 0x03391D90> male

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print objects of class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-objects-of-class-using-print)

Answer (score 0):

In your `student_details` function you print an object:

```
def student_details(self):
    print(self.firstname, self.lastname, self.age,self, self.gender)
                                                   ^
                                                   |
HERE ----------------------------------------------+
```

You didn't implemented `__str__` and `__repr__` functions inside the class so it prints the point to memory where your object is stored (it is the basic behavior). You should delete this `self` or replace it with `self.graduate_year` to print everything you want correctly.

Answer (score 0):

*Note I am running python 3.6.7

As mentioned by vurmux you need a `__str__` or`__repr__` functions inside your class. What is happening is that python is printing out the object id `<main.dateils object at 0x03391D90>` which is gibberish to us. A odd way of getting around this though is shown below. I have implemented a `__repr__` function where I define the instance of the class dateils (you might have meant details). Then I output the results. Also I might not sure if you meant to define self.age=17 but I left it as is and just fixed that one part.

```
class person:
    def __init__(self,fname,lname):
        self.firstname = fname
        self.lastname = lname

    def printname(self):
        print(self.firstname, self.lastname)

class student(person):
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,year):
        person.__init__(self,fname,lname)
        self.graduate_year = year

    def welcome(self):
        print("Welcome", self.firstname, self.lastname, self.graduate_year)

class dateils(person):
    def __init__(self,fname,lname, age, gender,):
        person.__init__(self, fname, lname)
        self.age =17
        self.gender = "male"

    def student_details(self):
        print(self.firstname, self.lastname, self.age, self.gender)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.firstname) + str(self.lastname) + str(self.age) + str(self.gender)

#Student
x = student("Enter your name:", "Enter your lastname: ", 2019)

x.welcome()

#person details
d = dateils(input("Enter your name"), input("Enter your lastname"), input("Enter your age"), input("Enter your gender"))
d.student_details()
```

See the following question for more about the two **str** and **repr**
[Difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)