# Get the "name" of a mock object (using a builtin method)

Tags: python, mocking

The `__repr__`esentation of a Mock object that has been obtained as an attribute (or as the return of `__call__`) of another Mock shows what looks like a `name` attribute. This pseudoattribute however doesn't seem to exist in the class. For example:

```py
>>> import mock
... x = mock.MagicMock()
... y = x.asdf
... z = y.hjkl
... a = z()

>>> a
<MagicMock name='mock.asdf.hjkl()' id='139706648472600'>

>>> 'name' in a.__dict__
False
```

In order to get this psuedoattribute, it seems that I can either parse the return of `y.__repr__()` or some sort of recursive function like this:

```py
def get_mock_name(some_mock):
    if some_mock._mock_name:
        return f'{get_mock_name(some_mock._mock_parent)}.{some_mock._mock_name}'
    elif some_mock._mock_new_name:
        return f'{get_mock_name(some_mock._mock_new_parent)}{some_mock._mock_new_name}'
    else:
        return 'mock'
```

While both work, is there any ***standard and/or builtin way*** of doing this?

Edit: no, I am not asking how to override `__repr__`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print objects of class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-objects-of-class-using-print)

Comment: @Alexander Santos how so? I am trying to get a specific piece of information that is already printed, not change the behavior of the print function.

Comment: You're getting back the `__repr__` method on the `Mock`. If you want to see how that is set, here is the source: `https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L693`

Comment: Fragile, but `__repr__` gets it from `a._extract_mock_name()`.

Comment: @chepner I'm afraid I don't understand. `a._extract_mock_name()` just returns another mock (`<MagicMock name='mock.asdf.hjkl()._extract_mock_name()' id='140672036897960'>`)  for me

Comment: Hm, could be a version issue. I only checked the [version that ships with Python 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L659). I see an older version of the 3rd-party module doesn't abstract out the name-building into a separate (private) method. Like I said: fragile :)

Comment: @chepner Ope, I think I'm using the 3rd party library. It makes sense that they've moved that out since. Thanks for that info! If you wrote that as an answer, I'd definitely accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for setting me up with this answer!

The "name" psuedo-attribute can be obtained with the [Mock._extract_mock_name()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/87b6078fb90f11dc67ad8f31e98cbc40f74fcb81/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L626) method of [the version of `mock` that ships with python 3.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.7/Lib/unittest).

This method is actually [used in the implementation of `__repr__` to get this information](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L659) encapsulating the behavior that was previously just a part the `__repr__` function.

You can use it like so:

```py
$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 19 2019, 10:33:54) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import unittest.mock as mock
>>> x = mock.MagicMock()
>>> y = x.asdf
>>> z = y.hjkl
>>> a = z()
>>> a._extract_mock_name()
'mock.asdf.hjkl()'
```