# What determines output when executing single variable in python interpreter?

Tags: python, output, pythoninterpreter

So take the complex built-in type as an example. I am making my own version of Complex for educational purposes, however as of now, they aren't behaving the same way.
When I run

```py
>>> a = (2+3j)
>>> a
(2+3j)
>>> from complex import Complex # My version of the type
>>> b = Complex(2, 3)
>>> b
<complex.Complex object at 0x10caeb0f0>
```

I want my class to output the same thing. I always thought that this was the purpose of the **str** magic method, but that only gets invoked when something is trying to convert the instance to string, which isn't happening in the example above. How to do this?

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: It just means that `Complex` doesn't have `__str__` method implemented.

Comment: have you looked at `__repr__`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `__repr__`:

```py
class Complex:
  def __init__(self, i, j):
    self.i = i
    self.j = j

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'({self.i}, {self.j}j)'

b = Complex(2, 3)
print(b)
```

Output:

```py
(2, 3j)
```