# Python Category methods

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and am learning about basic methods that can be used in Python in class. 
I have this homework problem that I do not really know how to solve, so I was wondering if you could help me with this.
Here is the problem:

```py
class Doughnut:
    categories = ['cakey', 'doughy']
    def __init__(self, category, flavor):
        if category not in Doughnut.categories:
            self.category = 'doughy'
        else:
            self.category = category
        self.flavor = flavor

    def ___________:
        return self.category + " " + self.flavor + "doughnuts" 

d = Doughnut('cakey', 'bacon')
print("I want 2 " + str(d) + "s please!") # I want 2 cakey bacon doughnuts please!
```

I need to know what to write in the blank statement between the second "def" and ":". 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should have a look at this:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `__str__()` method. A full working implementation is below.

```
class Doughnut:
  categories = ['cakey', 'doughy']


  def __init__(self, category, flavor):
    if category not in Doughnut.categories:
        self.category = 'doughy'
    else:
        self.category = category
    self.flavor = flavor


  def __str__(self):
    return self.category + " " + self.flavor + " doughnuts"


d = Doughnut('cakey', 'bacon')
print("I want 2 " + str(d) + "s please!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Both answers included in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print) would work.

You could use either `def __repr__(self):` or `def __str__(self):`

Comment: As @Maggyero mentioned in the comments, in that link the differences between repr and str are explained

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are [magic methods](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/magic-methods-in-python): when python is asked to do something non-trivial, it will search for one of them in your class to see how to do it.

In your specific case, there are two methods that convert a class to a string, and `str()` will try to use them under the hood:

- `__str__` is expected to return a human-readable representation
- `__repr__` should return a unambiguous representation

For more details, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr).

So I would suggest:

```py
def __str__:
    return self.category + " " + self.flavor + "doughnuts"
```