# How to compare an object to a string?

Tags: python

**Problem**

How do I compare an object made from a class to a string? I've added multiple objects to a list.
When I loop through the list:

```
for i in self._list:
   print(i)
```

It prints out this:

```
<sokker.Sokker object at 0x019E9A30>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to _compare_ an instance of the class to a string in the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you want to print an object. You can use [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) to do that using:

```py
list_of_objects = [my_object_one, my_object_two]
for object in list_of_objects:
  print(str(object))
```

It will call the `__str__()` of the `object` class and hopefully display the information you wish to see.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print) there is a similar question.

Just to resume, to print object it's class should have method `__str__()` defined, like here:

```py
class Test:
    def __str__(self):
        return "my custom text"
```