# How do i print actual data and not memory locations of an object?

Tags: python, object, linked-list

Im trying to make a linked list in python and would like to print out the things but its printing as a memory location. We learnt how to fix this in class but im on half term at the moment and have nobody to ask.

An example of what im currently getting:

```
List: <__main__.LinkedList object at 0x02EA0100>
 index: 0    data: 1     item: <__main__.Node object at 0x02EA00D0>  pointer: <__main__.Node object at 0x02EA0148>
 index: 1    data: 6     item: <__main__.Node object at 0x02EA0148>  pointer: <__main__.Node object at 0x02EA0190>
 index: 2    data: 3     item: <__main__.Node object at 0x02EA0190>  pointer: None
```

This is not very usefull to me.

The method im using to get this masterpice:

```
def PrintList(self):
    item = self.list_start
    index = 0
    print(f"List: {self}")
    while item:
        print(
            f"\t index: {index}\t data: {item.data}\t item: {item}\t pointer: {item._get_pointer()}"
            )
        item = item._get_pointer()
        index += 1
```

Im sure theres something wrong in the print line i just cant spot it.

I know your not supposed to put loads of code on here but i need to give context

Node Class:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, data=None, pointer=None):
    self.data = data
    self.poiner = pointer

def PrintNode(self):
    print(f"Node Data: {self.data}\t self: {self}\t pointer: {self.pointer}\n")

def _set_pointer(self, pointer):
    self.pointer = pointer

def _get_pointer(self):
    return self.pointer
```

LinkedLis Class:

```
class LinkedList:
def __init__(self):
    self.list_start = None

def PrintList(self):
    item = self.list_start
    index = 0
    print(f"List: {self}")
    while item:
        print(
            f"\t index: {index}\t data: {item.data}\t item: {item}\t pointer: {item._get_pointer()}"
            )
        item = item._get_pointer()
        index += 1

def _isleagl(self, node):
    if node is None:
        print(f"node' is None")
        return False
    elif type(node) != Node:
        print(f"'node' has worng type: {type(node)}")
        return False
    else:
        return True

def AppendNode(self, node):
    if self._isleagl(node):
        if self.list_start == None:
            self.list_start = node
            node._set_pointer(None)
        else:
            item = self.list_start
            while item:
                if item == node:
                    node = copy.deepcopy(node)
                elif item._get_pointer() is None:
                    item._set_pointer(node)

                    node._set_pointer(None)
                    break
                else:
                    item = item._get_pointer()

def DeleteNode(self, node):
    if self._islegal(node):
        if self.list_start == node:
            self.list_start = node._get_pointer()
        else:
            item = self.list_start
            while item:
                if item._get_pointer() == node:
                    item._set_pointer(node._get_pointer())
                break
            item = item._get_pointer()
```

Menu system:  #i dont think this is going to be of much help

```
def main():
my_list = None
my_node = None
while True:
    print("Node Manipulations")
    print("\t 0: Create Node")
    print("\t 1: Set Node Data")
    print("\t 2: Print Node")
    print()
    print("List Manipulations")
    print("\t 3: Create List")
    print("\t 4: Print List")
    print("\t 5: Append Node to List")
    print("\t 6: Delete Node from List")
    print()
    print("X: EXIT Program")
    choice = input("->")
    if choice not in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "X", "x"]:
        continue

    if choice == "X" or choice == "x":
         break

    elif choice == "0":
        my_node = Node()

    elif choice == "1":
        if my_node is None:
            print("Create Node first")
        else:
            my_node.data = input("Node Data? -> ")

    elif choice == "2":
        if my_node is None:
           print("Create Node first")
        else:
            my_node.PrintNode()

    elif choice == "3":
        my_list = LinkedList()

    elif choice == "4":
        if my_list is None:
           print("Create List first")
        else:
            my_list.PrintList()
            print()

    elif choice == "5":
        if my_list is None:
            print("Create List first")
        else:
            my_list.AppendNode(my_node)

    elif choice == "6":
        if my_list is None:
            print("Create List first")
        else:
            my_list.DeleteNode(my_node)
```

Comment: Nah, it's good. You print your `data` just next to that, so you get the useful contents, no? If you want to change what is printed when you print an object, you can implement `__str__(self)` and/or `__repr__(self)` method. But you'll probably print your `data` field in there anyways. Or maybe recursively print the whole list (just like build-in list displays contents, not the memory location), but then the loop seems obsolete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Comment: @h4z3 Im not sure what you mean. Could you please maybe provide me with like an example of how it would work? 

Specifically this line: `print(
            f"\t index: {index}\t data: {item.data}\t item: {item}\t pointer: {item._get_pointer()}"
            )`

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following code:

```
class K:
    pass

obj = K()
print(obj)
```

The output is:

```
<__main__.K object at 0x01481FE8>
```

By default, if you don't write a "to string" method (or `__str__()`) the garbage above is what python will produce as a string. Note that the function `print` can only print strings. It cannot print integers, or anything else. As such `print(n)` will convert all inputs to strings before printing them. The code below describes what the built-in `print` function does:

```
import sys
def print(*args, sep=" ", end"\n", file=sys.stdout):
    file.write(sep.join(map(str, args)) + end)
```

So, write your own `__str__` method:

```
import sys
import io
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, pointer=None):
        self.data = data
        self.pointer = pointer

    def print_node(self, *, sep="\t", file=sys.stdout):
        print(
            f"Node Data: {self.data}",
            f"self: {id(self)}",
            f"pointer: {id(self.pointer)}",
            sep=sep,
            file=file
        )

    def _set_pointer(self, pointer):
        self.pointer = pointer

    def _get_pointer(self):
        return self.pointer

    def __str__(self):
        with io.StringIO() as string_stream:
            self.print_node(file=string_stream)
            stryng = string_stream.getvalue()
        return stryng
```

Your print node method was originally named `PrintNode`. Never begin something with a capital letter unless it is a class. Either write `printNode` or `print_node`.

Secondly, I changed `f"pointer: {self.pointer}"` to `f"pointer: {id(self.pointer)}"`

Suppose that you did not do that. Well then, `print_node` would print `self.pointer`. But `self.pointer` is a node, so it would then print `self.pointer.pointer`. But `self.pointer.pointer` is a node, so then it would print `self.pointer.pointer.pointer`, and so on... You don't want that. The memory address of an object can be retrieved with the `id()` function.

Also, it's a bad idea for `print_node` to print self. That's just begging for an infinite recursion. How do I print `self`? well, I print `data`, `self`, and `pointer`. That means I gotta print `self`, which means I gotta print `self`, which means I gotta print `self`, and so on, forever, and ever.

Answer (score 0):

**"<**main**.K object at 0x01481FE8>"**
try
`xyz=str(x.data)`
`print(xyz)` xyz will give you data stored at that location.
use it in loop if you are using an list or any data structure.
faced similar problem in a program it helped.

Comment: rephrase "let your data is string" to remove confusion. You can edit and update your answer. Also use capitals when you start a new sentence. Last thing: welcome to and enjoy SO ;-) End of Review.