# How does value asignments within Tuples in Python work?

Tags: python, tuples

While working on a script in Python, I came accross this built-in method part of the sys module `sys.flags` which returns a tuple of flags used to run the python script. The output looks like:

```
(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=1, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0, dev_mode=False, utf8_mode=0)
```

I'm confused, as I thought you could not embed an assignment within another expression in Python, and so far I haven't been able to find an answer on Google that explains the behavior of this tuple.

Comment: `sys.flags` is not a tuple; `type(sys.flags)` reveals that much.

Comment: It isn't an assignment.

Comment: I think those are the current settings as opposed to assignments. There might be a `__str__` method that prints the output you are seeing as a reference, similar to what is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output doesn't show a `tuple`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.flags
sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0, dev_mode=False, utf8_mode=0)
>>> type(sys.flags)
<class 'sys.flags'>
```

A tuple would look like this:

```
>>> tuple(sys.flags)
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, False, 0)
```

It actually returns an instance of a class that has a custom representation.

Note that this is a typical representation for a "data-class". It shows how such an object was created or could be created. For example `namedtuple` have a similar representation (not an accident because [`sys.flags` is a `namedtuple`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Python/sysmodule.c#L2418-L2457)!):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name, age')
>>> Person(20, 'me')
Person(name=20, age='me')
>>> Person(name=20, age='me')
Person(name=20, age='me')
```

Answer (score 3):

The actual output is:

```
>>> sys.flags
sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0, dev_mode=False, utf8_mode=0)
```

That `sys.flags` before the opening parenthesis is crucial. It shows that `sys.flags` is something else than a tuple.

Yet you could totally create a class whose `__repr__` method would return this kind of tuple-like representation:

```
class Weird:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"(a={self.a}, b={self.b})"
```

Then the output will look like this:

```
>>> Weird(1,2)
(a=1, b=2)
```

But `Weird` is definitely not a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, doing:

```
isinstance(sys.flags, tuple)
```

will return `True`. But that is because [`sys.flags`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.flags) is a [`named-tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-named-tuple), which inherits from the `tuple` type. From the docs:

> The term “named tuple” applies to any type or class that inherits from
>   tuple and whose indexable elements are also accessible using named
>   attributes.