# How do I use a record defined as a games object to save multiple records data and then print it too

Tags: python, class, object, record

I'm new to Python wondered if someone could explain how I can use this games object to save to when user inputs all the different variables and then print the results.

```
Class games:
   def __init__(self, name, platform, genre, no_of_players, online_functionality):
        self.name = name
        self.platform = platform
        self.genre = genre
        self.players = no_of_players
        self.functionality = online_functionality
        games.games_list.append(self)
```

Comment: Use a list or dictionary to store instances of this class. Also, name it `Game` rather than `games`

Comment: Can you explain little more what is the problem here?

Comment: In another function I will be getting user input for the variables name, platform etc. How do I use my games object to save the data and then also print from it. I especially don't know how I can print from this object?

Comment: Create new game instances with new_game = Games() and pass the data as arguments inside the parens like listed in the __init__ def line.

Comment: I have stored instances of this class in a list and am getting this [<__main__.games object at 0x042193B8>] when trying to print the instances of the class entered by the user? can anyone explain how I can successfully code printing the records?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)