# How to print out node object

Tags: python

```
lyst = file()

class Node:  
    def __init__(self,first,next=()):
        self.first = first
        self.next = next
    
def recursivelist(lyst):
    assert len(lyst) > 0
    if len(lyst) == 1:
        return Node(lyst[0])
    else:
        return Node(lyst[0],recursivelist(lyst[1:]))

print(recursivelist(lyst))
```

This will return just this: <**main**.Node object at 0x7f976fd24130>

When I am wanting to actually see it. Is there any way I can actually do that? I saw online that I can use the **str** method in the class, but I have no idea how to implement that.

Any help would be extremely helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the __repr__ and/or the __str__ function for your class, in this method you can clarify how you want an instance of your class to be represented when printed like that.

See documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#repr
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-str

Comment: i just want to print out the linked list

Comment: Then you can implement the repr/str missions respectively for them to print out the next part of the list, since it's in the node.