# <__main__.Employee object at 0x000001E32362C1F0>

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,first,last,salary):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.salary = salary
    
emp_1 = Employee("Rohan","Parab",100000)
print(emp_1)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and please ask a proper question. In any case, this is most likely a duplicate of [How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535327/2745495)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the `__str__` method otherwise it will print (as you may have observed) the object location.

For example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"First Name: {self.first}, Last Name {self.last}, Salary {self.salary}"
```