# Why am I receiving this AttributeError: 'Contact' object has no attribute 'print_entry'?

Tags: python, attributeerror

I was given the code that begins with the print_directory function and told not to alter anything below that. I've created the contact class above. Why am I receiving the attribute error, and how would I fix it? I'm trying to create a class that uses the variables in the main function to return the first name, last name, and phone numbers of the contacts list.

My code is below:

```
class Contact:
    fname = ""
    lname = ""
    p_number = ""
    
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,p_number):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.p_number = p_number
        
    def getfname(self):
        return self.fname
    
    def getlname(self):
        return self.lname
    
    def getp_number(self):
        return self.p_number


def print_directory(contacts):
    print("My Contacts")
    print("-----------")
    for person in contacts:
        person.print_entry()
    print("-----------\n")

# -----------------------------------------------------

def main():
    champ = Contact("???", "Bobcat", "406-994-0000")
    president = Contact("Waded", "Cruzado", "406-994-CATS")
    professor = Contact("John", "Paxton", "406-994-4780")

    contacts = [champ, president, professor]

    print_directory(contacts)

    champ.set_first_name("Champ")
    president.set_title("President")
    professor.set_title("Professor")

    print_directory(contacts)

    print("The area code for cell number", champ.get_cell_number(), "is", \
           champ.get_area_code())

# -----------------------------------------------------

main()
```

Comment: You need to add a method `print_entry` in you `Contact` class.

Comment: Where are `.set_first_name` and `.set_title` defined?

Comment: what exactly is the point of setting those class variables to empty strings (or declaring them at all)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will throw `AttributeError: 'Contact' object has no attribute 'print_entry'` because in your `Contact` class the method `print_entry` isn't defined.

Additionally you will also need to define `set_first_name`, and `set_title` in your `Contact` class or any lines where you call these class methods will throw a similar AttributeError.

You can add a definition for `print_entry` like this:

```
class Contact:
...
    def print_entry(self):
        # add your desired print statement here
...
```

Then use a similar structure to add your `set_first_name` and `set_title` methods. Something like this:

```
class Contact:
...
    def set_first_name(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
...
```

However it is unclear which instance variable you want `set_title` to modify. You might consider adding another instance variable called `title` to your class.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it's seem that you trying to call a method that not exist for the "Contact" class.

```
person.print_entry()
```

the class Contact does not know to do with that call.

maybe you have to implement an print_entry() method in the class:

```
class Contact:
    fname = ""
    lname = ""
    p_number = ""
    
    def __init__(self,fname,lname,p_number):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.p_number = p_number
        
    def getfname(self):
        return self.fname
    
    def getlname(self):
        return self.lname
    
    def getp_number(self):
        return self.p_number
    
    def print_entry(self):
        print(f" Name: {self.lname}, {self.fname}, Number: {self.p_number}")
```

Comment: This solution fixes exactly the issue asked for. Additionally it shows an elegant and idiomatic way of printing an entry with __[f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)__ (the standard in Python 3, see [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)). Providing links that elaborate concepts or methods (like Attribute-Error or f-strings) will make an answer even more helpful.

Comment: @hc_dev thanks! thats a pretty kind comment! here a heart for you <3

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:  Define a method `print_entry(self)` that uses `print` to output as expected (this solution was already answered).

A more idiomatic, object-oriented and maintainable solution would be to use `__str__` and `print` in two different levels (see below).

### Background

#### Attribute Error explained

This is always a signal that your class or a third-party class is missing some attributes that you referenced, like accessed fields or invoked methods.

So you need to define it or if a third-party module used via `import`, you should check version-mismatches, etc.

#### Printing an object's representation

In almost every object-oriented programming-language there is a method that converts the object instance to a string representation. In Python this is either `__repr__(self)` or `__str__(self)` (similar like `toString()` in Java). These are standard methods (recognize by the surrounding double underscores `__`) that already exist and usually can be overridden.

### Solution

Instead calling and defining `print_entry` instance-method, override the `__str__` method like:

```py
class Contact:
    # omitted other to focus on string method
    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: " + self.last_name + ", " + self.first_name;
```

and use it to print a `Contact` object instance `person` like:
`print(person)`

See also:
[How to print instances of a class using print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print)

**Benefits:**

- this is an object-oriented pattern, reusing Python's standard
- keeping all `print` statements in one place (principle: abstraction-level, code-symmetry) like in your method `print_directory`
- string-representation (`__str__`) separated from UI/output-layer (`print`) so that they can be changed independently (principle: separation of concerns & single-responsibility)

### Bonus

Tips:

- use an IDE like PyCharm (free community edition) or Eric, that will warn you in advance and offers quick-fix actions to add the missing attributes (methods, etc.).
- python naming convention for fields and methods is both **lower snake-case**, e.g. `first_name`
- setters need to be defined too, i.e. `set_first_name(self)`, `set_title(self)`
- getters used for `get_cell_number` and `get_area_code` are missing in class (whereas there is a field `p_number` with getter
- meaningful names instead abbreviations usually pay-off in the long-run: `phone_number` can be distinguished from `person_number` (some IDEs offer dictionary-assisted auto-completion and will pass spellchecking this way)
- a pythonic way for string-interpolation using templates (since Python 3) are [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) (see applied in [Ulises answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69667543/5730279))