# Why am I not getting the string but the None value

Tags: python

I am new in python so the question might seem silly. My code is below:
edited getting the kind feedback from @Mani and @Hashir Irfan

```
class University:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__university = None
        
    def get_university(self):
        return self.__university
    
    def add_university(self, university_string):
        # can edit only this method
        self.__university = university_string
        return self.__university

def main():
    print(University().get_university()) # success, giving None
    print(University().add_university('name')) # success, giving 'name'
    print(University().get_university()) # fail: giving None but expecting 'name' 

main()
```

How can I get the last one as 'name', that is self.__university get fully replaced by the 'name'? (I tried both @classmethod and @staticmethod but not worked.)

Comment: `add_university('Open University')` returns nothing from it, you have to return in this function

Comment: Is there any way that I can get the output 'Open University'? The 'None' value is not getting replaced.

Comment: Your function does not return anything, so the output is None. The value is replaced..

Comment: `university = University()` `university.add_university('Open University')` `print(university.__university)`

Answer (score 2):

The function return nothing that is why you are getting None.
Either call get_university after add_university or return in add_university

Do this

```
def add_university(self, university_string):
    self.__university = university_string
    return self.__university
```

or this

```
def main():
    u = University()
    u.add_university('Open University')
    print(u.get_university())
```

Comment: Second one looking good, without changing functions

Comment: Thanks. I tried accordingly. Now new problem has occurred... 

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works:

```
class University:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__university = None
        
    def get_university(self):
        return self.__university
    
    def add_university(self, university_string):
        self.__university = university_string
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__university
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__university
        
def main():
    u = University()
    u.add_university("Open University")
    print(u)

main()
```

When you tried `print(University().add_university("Open University"))`, it always printed `None`, because add_university does not return anything to print. In the absence of something to print, you get `None`.

For example, if you initialized `__university` to `"Default University"`, it would still print `None`. It was just tricky, because you thought `__university` was getting printed, and its value was `None`. Giving it a variable name `u` and writing `print(u)` will print something like `<__main__.University object at 0x7f15e3e344c0>`, which is an address in memory associated with `u`. Overriding the `__str__` method gives `print` something else to print when you pass it an object of type `University` rather than it using the default implementation that prints an address. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535327/how-to-print-instances-of-a-class-using-print) is a similar question, asking about printing an object. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr/2626364#2626364) is a nice, in-depth answer to the differences between `__str__` and `__repr__`, which both generate strings based on an object.

You might want to consider making your constructor take a university string rather than having a misleading `University` object that contains nothing in it, meaning it's practically misleading. Something like this would work:

```
class University:

    def __init__(self, university):
        self.__university = university

    def get_university(self):
        return self.__university

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__university

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__university

def main():
    print(University("Open University"))

main()
```

Notice how I removed `University::add_university`. It's kind of a mysterious operation to add a university to something that represents the entirety of a university already.  Instead, rely on your constructor setting it when you create a `University`, and restrict users of your class to treat a `University` as immutable (it cannot be changed). When things are constant in your code, it reduces bugs. If someone needs a different `University`, he can create a new one with the appropriate argument to its constructor.